# Remove Punctuation issue

Tags: java

Im trying to find a word in a string. However, due to a period it fails to recognize one word. Im trying to remove punctuation, however it seems to have no effect. Am I missing something here? This is the line of code I am using: **s.replaceAll("([a-z] +) [?:!.,;]*","$1");**

```
String test = "This is a line about testing tests. Tests are used to examine stuff";
    String key = "tests";
    int counter = 0;


    String[] testArray = test.toLowerCase().split(" ");

    for(String s : testArray)
    {
        s.replaceAll("([a-z] +) [?:!.,;]*","$1");
        System.out.println(s);
        if(s.equals(key))
        {
            System.out.println(key + " FOUND");
            counter++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(key + " has been found " + counter + " times.");
}
```

I managed to find a solution (though may not be ideal) through using **s = s.replaceAll("\W","")**; Thanks for everyones guidance on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Take a look at this question and the selected answer:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767759/occurences-of-substring-in-a-string][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767759/occurences-of-substring-in-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also take advantage of the regex in the split operation.  Try this:

```
String[] testArray = test.toLowerCase().split("\\W+");
```

This will split on apostrophe, so you may need to tweak it a bit with a specific list of characters.

Comment: Thanks, reached a similar answer also

Answer (score 1):

`Strings` are immutable. You would need assign the result of `replaceAll` to the new `String`:

```
s = s.replaceAll("([a-z] +)*[?:!.,;]*", "$1");
                           ^
```

Also your regex requires that a space exist between the word and the the punctuation. In the case of `tests.`, this isn't true. You can adjust you regex with an optional (zero or more) character to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't seem to work as you want.
If you want to find something which has period after that then this will work

```
([a-z]*) [?(:!.,;)*]
```

it returns "tests." when it's run on your given string.

Also

```
[?(:!.,;)*]
```

just points out the punctuation which will then can be replaced.

However I am not sure why you are not using substring() function.