# Count the number of Occurrences of a Word in a String

Tags: java, regex, string

I am new to Java Strings the problem is that I want to count the Occurrences of a specific word in a String. Suppose that my String is:

```
i have a male cat. the color of male cat is Black
```

Now I dont want to split it as well so I want to search for a word that is "male cat". it occurs two times in my string!

What I am trying is:

```
int c = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < text.length(); j++) {
    if (text.contains("male cat")) {
        c += 1;
    }
}

System.out.println("counter=" + c);
```

it gives me 46 counter value! So whats the solution?

Comment: Can you describe how do you think this code works (or you wish it to work)? This will help us help you better.

Comment: Also what should be result if you would like to search `aa` in `aaaa`? Would it be `2` or `3`?

Comment: i have given an example string so that the output should be 2 because male cat occurs 2 times in the string

Comment: Don't know Java, but depending on what you want to do, if its got a non-regex find first string util that lets you specify the start position each time in a loop (C++ 'string' class has this), it should be much faster.

Comment: Ok, I looked it up. All you need is `while((newndx=str.indexOf("male cat",oldndx))>-1){found++;oldndx=newndx+8;}`

Comment: Same kind of problem solved here ==> https://stackoverflow.com/a/767910/7561647

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
String in = "i have a male cat. the color of male cat is Black";
int i = 0;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("male cat");
Matcher m = p.matcher( in );
while (m.find()) {
    i++;
}
System.out.println(i); // Prints 2
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/uUcvzR)

## What it does?

It matches `"male cat"`.

```
while(m.find())
```

indicates, do whatever is given inside the loop while `m` finds a match.
And I'm incrementing the value of `i` by `i++`, so obviously, this gives number of `male cat` a string has got.

Comment: Good job. Now OP has code he don't understand but at least it work.

Answer (score 15):

If you just want the count of `"male cat"` then I would just do it like this:

```
String str = "i have a male cat. the color of male cat is Black";
int c = str.split("male cat").length - 1;
System.out.println(c);
```

and if you want to make sure that `"female cat"` is not matched then use `\\b` word boundaries in the split regex:

```
int c = str.split("\\bmale cat\\b").length - 1;
```

Comment: This was really easy. In one of my interview they asked me write in one or two line and this is the perfect match. Thanks Again.

Comment: I'm guessing this wont work in the case of the String ending with the search word. For.e.g:
"i have a male cat. the color of male cat"

Answer (score 13):

[StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) in apache commons-lang have **CountMatches** method to counts the number of occurrences of one String in another.

```
   String input = "i have a male cat. the color of male cat is Black";
   int occurance = StringUtils.countMatches(input, "male cat");
   System.out.println(occurance);
```

Answer (score 6):

Java 8 version.

```
System.out.println(Pattern.compile("\\bmale cat")
            .splitAsStream("i have a male cat. the color of male cat is Black")
            .count()-1);
```

Answer (score 5):

Java 8 version:

```
    public static long countNumberOfOccurrencesOfWordInString(String msg, String target) {
    return Arrays.stream(msg.split("[ ,\\.]")).filter(s -> s.equals(target)).count();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This `static` method does returns the number of occurrences of a string on another string.

```
/**
 * Returns the number of appearances that a string have on another string.
 * 
 * @param source    a string to use as source of the match
 * @param sentence  a string that is a substring of source
 * @return the number of occurrences of sentence on source 
 */
public static int numberOfOccurrences(String source, String sentence) {
    int occurrences = 0;

    if (source.contains(sentence)) {
        int withSentenceLength    = source.length();
        int withoutSentenceLength = source.replace(sentence, "").length();
        occurrences = (withSentenceLength - withoutSentenceLength) / sentence.length();
    }

    return occurrences;
}
```

**Tests:**

```
String source = "Hello World!";
numberOfOccurrences(source, "Hello World!");   // 1
numberOfOccurrences(source, "ello W");         // 1
numberOfOccurrences(source, "l");              // 3
numberOfOccurrences(source, "fun");            // 0
numberOfOccurrences(source, "Hello");          // 1
```

---

BTW, the method could be written in one line, awful, but it also works :)

```
public static int numberOfOccurrences(String source, String sentence) {
    return (source.contains(sentence)) ? (source.length() - source.replace(sentence, "").length()) / sentence.length() : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

using indexOf...

```
public static int count(String string, String substr) {
    int i;
    int last = 0;
    int count = 0;
    do {
        i = string.indexOf(substr, last);
        if (i != -1) count++;
        last = i+substr.length();
    } while(i != -1);
    return count;
}

public static void main (String[] args ){
    System.out.println(count("i have a male cat. the color of male cat is Black", "male cat"));
}
```

That will show: 2

Another implementation for count(), in just 1 line:

```
public static int count(String string, String substr) {
    return (string.length() - string.replaceAll(substr, "").length()) / substr.length() ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not recursive ?

```
public class CatchTheMaleCat  {
    private static final String MALE_CAT = "male cat";
    static int count = 0;
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        wordCount("i have a male cat. the color of male cat is Black");
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    private static boolean wordCount(String str){
        if(str.contains(MALE_CAT)){
            count++;
            return wordCount(str.substring(str.indexOf(MALE_CAT)+MALE_CAT.length()));
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

public class TestWordCount {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int count = numberOfOccurences("Alice", "Alice in wonderland. Alice & chinki are classmates. Chinki is better than Alice.occ");
    System.out.println("count : "+count);

}

public static int numberOfOccurences(String findWord, String sentence) {

    int length = sentence.length();
    int lengthWithoutFindWord = sentence.replace(findWord, "").length();
    return (length - lengthWithoutFindWord)/findWord.length();

}
```

}

Comment: While writing answer dont directly put the code explain the answer. Here is a document which explains how to answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

**This will work**

```
int word_count(String text,String key){
   int count=0;
   while(text.contains(key)){
      count++;
      text=text.substring(text.indexOf(key)+key.length());
   }
   return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the String that needs to be counted with empty string and then use the length without the string to calculate the number of occurrence.

```
public int occurrencesOf(String word)
    {
    int length = text.length();
    int lenghtofWord = word.length();
    int lengthWithoutWord = text.replace(word, "").length();
    return (length - lengthWithoutWord) / lenghtofWord ;
    }
```

Comment: Better to use replaceAll()

Answer (score 0):

Once you find the term you need to remove it from String under process so that it won't resolve the same again, use `indexOf()` and `substring()` , you don't need to do contains check length times

Comment: i am not getting you!

Comment: may not work as he didn't specify the behavior in case if he searches for 'male male' and there is 'male male male' string - is it 1 or 2 matches.

Answer (score 0):

The string contains that string all the time when looping through it. You don't want to ++ because what this is doing right now is just getting the length of the string if it contains " "male cat"

You need to indexOf() / substring()

Kind of get what i am saying?

Answer (score 0):

If you find the String you are searching for, you can go on for the length of that string (if in case you search aa in aaaa you consider it 2 times).

```
int c=0;
String found="male cat";
 for(int j=0; j<text.length();j++){
     if(text.contains(found)){
         c+=1;
         j+=found.length()-1;
     }
 }
 System.out.println("counter="+c);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be a faster non-regex solution.
(note -  Not a Java programmer)

```
 String str = "i have a male cat. the color of male cat is Black";
 int found  = 0;
 int oldndx = 0;
 int newndx = 0;

 while ( (newndx=str.indexOf("male cat", oldndx)) > -1 )
 {
     found++;
     oldndx = newndx+8;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways for the occurrence of substring and two of theme are:-

```
public class Test1 {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String st = "abcdsfgh yfhf hghj gjgjhbn hgkhmn abc hadslfahsd abcioh abc  a ";
    count(st, 0, "a".length());

}

public static void count(String trim, int i, int length) {
    if (trim.contains("a")) {
        trim = trim.substring(trim.indexOf("a") + length);
        count(trim, i + 1, length);
    } else {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public static void countMethod2() {
    int index = 0, count = 0;
    String inputString = "mynameiskhanMYlaptopnameishclMYsirnameisjasaiwalmyfrontnameisvishal".toLowerCase();
    String subString = "my".toLowerCase();

    while (index != -1) {
        index = inputString.indexOf(subString, index);
        if (index != -1) {
            count++;
            index += subString.length();
        }
    }
    System.out.print(count);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can count from many ways for the occurrence of substring:-

```
public class Test1 {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String st = "abcdsfgh yfhf hghj gjgjhbn hgkhmn abc hadslfahsd abcioh abc  a ";
    count(st, 0, "a".length());

}

public static void count(String trim, int i, int length) {
    if (trim.contains("a")) {
        trim = trim.substring(trim.indexOf("a") + length);
        count(trim, i + 1, length);
    } else {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public static void countMethod2() {
    int index = 0, count = 0;
    String inputString = "mynameiskhanMYlaptopnameishclMYsirnameisjasaiwalmyfrontnameisvishal".toLowerCase();
    String subString = "my".toLowerCase();

    while (index != -1) {
        index = inputString.indexOf(subString, index);
        if (index != -1) {
            count++;
            index += subString.length();
        }
    }
    System.out.print(count);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got another approach here:

```
String description = "hello india hello india hello hello india hello";
String textToBeCounted = "hello";

// Split description using "hello", which will return 
//string array of words other than hello
String[] words = description.split("hello");

// Get number of characters words other than "hello"
int lengthOfNonMatchingWords = 0;
for (String word : words) {
    lengthOfNonMatchingWords += word.length();
}

// Following code gets length of `description` - length of all non-matching
// words and divide it by length of word to be counted
System.out.println("Number of matching words are " + 
(description.length() - lengthOfNonMatchingWords) / textToBeCounted.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete Example here,

```
package com.test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class WordsOccurances {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

            String sentence = "Java can run on many different operating "
                + "systems. This makes Java platform independent.";

            String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
            Map<String, Integer> wordsMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            for (int i = 0; i<words.length; i++ ) {
                if (wordsMap.containsKey(words[i])) {
                    Integer value = wordsMap.get(words[i]);
                    wordsMap.put(words[i], value + 1);
                } else {
                    wordsMap.put(words[i], 1);
                }
            }

            /*Now iterate the HashMap to display the word with number 
           of time occurance            */

           Iterator it = wordsMap.entrySet().iterator();
           while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, Integer> entryKeyValue = (Map.Entry<String, Integer>) it.next();
                System.out.println("Word : "+entryKeyValue.getKey()+", Occurance : "
                                +entryKeyValue.getValue()+" times");
           }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class WordCount {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String scentence = "This is a treeis isis is is is";
    String word = "is";
    int wordCount = 0;
    for(int i =0;i<scentence.length();i++){
        if(word.charAt(0) == scentence.charAt(i)){
            if(i>0){
                if(scentence.charAt(i-1) == ' '){
                    if(i+word.length()<scentence.length()){
                        if(scentence.charAt(i+word.length()) != ' '){
                            continue;}
                        }
                    }
                else{
                    continue;
                }
            }
            int count = 1;
            for(int j=1 ; j<word.length();j++){
                i++;
                if(word.charAt(j) != scentence.charAt(i)){
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if(count == word.length()){
                wordCount++;
            }

        }
    }
    System.out.println("The word "+ word + " was repeated :" + wordCount);
}
```

}

Comment: Just code is not always self explanatory, you should consider adding comments inside the code and also Explain how this work, this will help other's understand how this works along with just a working code

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution is here-**

Below code uses HashMap as it will maintain keys and values. so here keys will be word and values will be count (occurance of a word in a given string).

```
public class WordOccurance 
{

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
    String str = "avinash pande avinash pande avinash";

    //split the word with white space       
    String words[] = str.split(" ");
    for (String word : words) 
    {   
        //If already added/present in hashmap then increment the count by 1
        if(hm.containsKey(word))    
        {           
            hm.put(word, hm.get(word)+1);
        }
        else //if not added earlier then add with count 1
        {
            hm.put(word, 1);
        }

    }
    //Iterate over the hashmap
    Set<Entry<String, Integer>> entry =  hm.entrySet();
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry2 : entry) 
    {
        System.out.println(entry2.getKey() + "      "+entry2.getValue());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public int occurrencesOf(String word) {
    int length = text.length();
    int lenghtofWord = word.length();
    int lengthWithoutWord = text.replaceAll(word, "").length();
    return (length - lengthWithoutWord) / lenghtofWord ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for scala it's just 1 line

def numTimesOccurrenced(text:String, word:String) =text.split(word).size-1