# Program terminates without printing anything

Tags: java, string

I am trying to print a line from the listed file, which contains a word stated. But the program does nothing. Can someone help me with the code? Thanks

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class SearchingArrayLists {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      ArrayList names = new ArrayList();
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("random.txt"));

      while (scan.hasNext()){
        names.add(scan.next());
      }

      if (names.contains("legal")){
      System.out.println(scan.next());
      }

      scan.close();

    }

}
```

UPDATE:

Sorry, removed the loop. the file contains random text where the word "legal" is in there. the file was read by the scanner beforehand.

Comment: Why the empty `for` loop?

Comment: what does `random.txt` contain?
And is the file getting read by scanner?

Comment: Does random.txt contain the word legal also there won't be a next() here:`System.out.println(scan.next());` because you have already iterated through the entire file.

Comment: As a side note try [not to use raw types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). Use `ArrayList<String>` instead of solely `ArrayList`.

Comment: Sorry removed the loop. the file contains random text where the word "legal" is in there. the file was read by the scanner beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("random.txt"));
  String name = "" ;
  while (scan.hasNextLine()){
    name  = scan.nextLine();
   if (name.contains("legal")){
  System.out.println(name);
  }
}




  scan.close();
```

Try above code , you even don't need list. I have not compiled it , so remove if any syntax error you got.

Comment: Hey, this works good thanks but i would like it so it displays the line the word is on. I should have made this more clear. Thanks

Comment: you tried this ?? is it not displaying whole line ? sorry i am not not having jvm and ide with me right now

Comment: Yeah, i tried it it prints the word. I would like it so it prints the row though

Comment: One more thing if you don't mind. Do you know how to do it so it counts how many times the word is in there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767759/occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string refer this for getting in each line and you can put variable outside loop and keep adding it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66488/discussion-between-the-no-1-and-panther).

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println(scan.next());` will throw an exception, since you are calling it after you consumed all the input in the `while (scan.hasNext())` loop.

But it may not even reach that exception if your `names` list doesn't contain an exact match to the String "legal".