# Clojure count words in a string

Tags: clojure

```
string = "bonjor hello how are you you you";
```

Can anybody provide me with the code to count how many times the word `you` is within the string? I just cant get it.

Greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767759/occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string

Comment: It's clojure I need the help with

Answer (score 1):

hey check these and let me know if still have any doubt

```
(def data "bonjor hello how are you you you")    
(count (re-seq #"you" data))
```

check documentation of 
[re-seq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/re-seq) and [count](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/count) for detail.

detailed documentation available here:

[Grimoire](http://conj.io/) and
[clojure docs](http://clojuredocs.org/)