# Java - Add numbers to matching words

Tags: java

I'm trying to add a count number for matching words, like this:

> Match word: "Text"
>
> Input: Text Text Text TextText ExampleText
>
> Output: Text1 Text2 Text3 Text4Text5 ExampleText6

I have tried this:

```
String text = "Text Text Text TextText ExampleText";
String match = "Text";
int i = 0;
while(text.indexOf(match)!=-1) {
text = text.replaceFirst(match, match + i++);
}
```

Doesn't work because it would loop forever, the match stays in the string and IndexOf will never stop.

What would you suggest me to do?
Is there a better way doing this?

Comment: Consider using two strings, one for original data and one for modified. Possible improvements: use StringBuilder, use regex expressions.

Comment: create a second String, in which you write the parts you have already "adjusted". Then, remove it from the original String, so that the while indexof will eventually return -1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767759/occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string Might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one with a `StringBuilder` but no need to split:

```
public static String replaceWithNumbers( String text, String match ) {
    int matchLength = match.length();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( text );

    int index = 0;
    int i = 1;
    while ( ( index = sb.indexOf( match, index )) != -1 ) {
        String iStr = String.valueOf(i++);
        sb.insert( index + matchLength, iStr );

        // Continue searching from the end of the inserted text
        index += matchLength + iStr.length();
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Cool. It looks like my solution. ;-)

Comment: @SubOptimal Could be. I've been testing it before I posted, you may have posted earlier. BTW, have you tested your code when the string to match is a digit?

Answer (score 2):

first take one stringbuffer i.e. result,Then spilt the source with the match(destination).
It results in an array of blanks and remaining words except "Text".
then check condition for isempty and depending on that replace the array position.

```
String text = "Text Text Text TextText ExampleText";
    String match = "Text";
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String[] split = text.split(match);
    for(int i=0;i<split.length;){
        if(split[i].isEmpty())
            result.append(match+ ++i);
        else
            result.append(split[i]+match+ ++i);
    }
    System.out.println("Result is =>"+result);
```

O/P
Result is => `Text1 Text2 Text3 Text4Text5 ExampleText6`

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution is tested

```
    String text = "Text Text Text TextText Example";
    String match = "Text";
    String lastWord=text.substring(text.length() -match.length());

    boolean lastChar=(lastWord.equals(match));

    String[] splitter=text.split(match);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0;i<splitter.length;i++)
    {

       if(i!=splitter.length-1)
           splitter[i]=splitter[i]+match+Integer.toString(i);
       else
          splitter[i]=(lastChar)?splitter[i]+match+Integer.toString(i):splitter[i];

       sb.append(splitter[i]);
       if (i != splitter.length - 1) {
           sb.append("");
       }
    }
    String joined = sb.toString();
    System.out.print(joined+"\n");
```

Comment: please give me new text you test it. to check fix the issue

Comment: @DeveloperH Use for example `text = "Text Text Text TextText ExampleTex"` and the `match = "Text"` the result is `Text0 Text1 Text2 Text3Text4 ExampleTexText5`. Use my solution and it works. ;-)

Comment: I just finished the issue.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution could be

```
String text = "Text Text Text TextText ExampleText";
String match = "Text";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
int occurence = 1;
int offset = 0;
while ((offset = sb.indexOf(match, offset)) != -1) {
    // fixed this after comment from @RealSkeptic
    String insertOccurence = Integer.toString(occurence);
    sb.insert(offset + match.length(), insertOccurence);
    offset += match.length() + insertOccurence.length();
    occurence++;
}
System.out.println("result: " + sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Text Text Text TextText ExampleText";
    int count=0;
    while(s.contains("Text")){
        s=s.replaceFirst("Text", "*"+ ++count); // replace each occurrence of "Text" with some place holder which is not in your main String.
    }
    s=s.replace("*","Text");
    System.out.println(s);


}
```

O/P:

```
Text1 Text2 Text3 Text4Text5 ExampleText6
```

Comment: What if there will be * in text ? you should use another sign like Bell character or smth.

Comment: @Milkmaid - I was editing my answer.. You have to choose something which is not present in the string

Answer (score 0):

I refactored @DeveloperH 's code to this:

```
public class Snippet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String matchWord = "Text";
        String input = "Text Text Text TextText ExampleText";
        String output = addNumbersToMatchingWords(matchWord, input);
        System.out.print(output);
    }

    private static String addNumbersToMatchingWords(String matchWord, String input) {
        String[] inputsParts = input.split(matchWord);

        StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        for (String inputPart : inputsParts) {
            outputBuilder.append(inputPart);
            outputBuilder.append(matchWord);
            outputBuilder.append(i);
            if (i != inputsParts.length - 1)
                outputBuilder.append(" ");
            i++;
        }
        return outputBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice work. I edit my answer. please check my answer then edit it yours

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this by using stringbuilder, it provides simplest construct to insert character in a string. Following is the code

```
    String text = "Text Text Text TextText ExampleText";
    String match = "Text";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
    int beginIndex = 0, i =0;
    int matchLength = match.length();
    while((beginIndex = sb.indexOf(match, beginIndex))!=-1) {
         i++;
         sb.insert(beginIndex+matchLength, i);
         beginIndex++;
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```