# Find all occurrences of substring in string in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

I'm trying to find all occurrences of a substring in a string in Java.

For example:
searching "ababsdfasdfhelloasdf" for "asdf" would return [8,17] since there are 2 "asdf"'s, one at position 8 and one at 17.
Searching "aaaaaa" for "aa" would return [0,1,2,3,4] because there is an "aa" at positions 0,1,2,3, and 4.

I tried this:

```
public List<Integer> findSubstrings(String inwords, String inword) {
    String copyOfWords = inwords;
    List<Integer> indicesOfWord = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int currentStartIndex = niwords.indexOf(inword);
    int indexat = 0;
    System.out.println(currentStartIndex);
    while (cthing1 > 0) {
        indicesOfWord.add(currentStartIndex+indexat);
        System.out.println(currentStartIndex);
        System.out.println(indicesOfWord);
        indexat += cthing1;
        copyOfWords = copyOfWords.substring(cthing1);
        System.out.println(copyOfWords);
        cthing1 = copyOfWords.indexOf(inword);
    }
```

This problem can be solved in Python as follows:

```
indices = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(word, a.lower())]
```

where "word" is the word I'm looking for and "a" is the string I'm searching through.

How can I achieve this in Java?

Comment: I think the top post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767759/occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string) may help you. For getting the indexes, just print or save the `lastIndex` as you receive them.

Comment: Do you mean you need [something like this](http://ideone.com/9IeCEQ)?

Comment: Please use more meaningful variable names. It's hard to understand what `cthing1` or `outthing` or `niwords` mean. Using things like `lastIndex`, `indexList`, etc. Would make it easier to understand what you wrote and correct it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use capturing inside a positive look-ahead to get all overlapping matches and use `Matcher#start` to get the indices of the captured substrings.

As for [the regex](https://regex101.com/r/yI1tB7/1), it will look like

```
(?=(aa))
```

In Java code:

```
String s = "aaaaaa";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?=(aa))").matcher(s);
List<Integer> pos = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while (m.find())
{
    pos.add(m.start());
}
System.out.println(pos);
```

Result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/q96Obu)

Answer (score 5):

Using a regex is definitely an overly heavy solution for finding substrings, and it'll especially be a problem if your substring contains special regex characters like `.`. Here's a solution adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/767910/2482744):

```
String str = "helloslkhellodjladfjhello";
String findStr = "hello";
int lastIndex = 0;
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while(lastIndex != -1) {

    lastIndex = str.indexOf(findStr,lastIndex);

    if(lastIndex != -1){
        result.add(lastIndex);
        lastIndex += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This returns [0,2,4] for "aa" NOT [0,1,2,3,4] as the poster wanted. Need to  increment lastIndex only by 1 not length of findStr to find all sub-matches.

Comment: You are correct, forgot the overlapping part. Editing.