# list all next word of matching word in java

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have used below function to print next word.

But it prints only first matching word,How to print all words?

string example = " 123 :G Hi all P: word I am new in java :G help me :N abc  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 :R 56 0 0 :G Please;
string matchWord= ":G";

```
public String nextWord(String str, String matchWord) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(matchWord + "\\W+(\\w+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    return m.find() ? m.group(1) : null;
}
```

Current output: Hi
Expected Output: Hi help Please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all occurrences of substring in string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788407/find-all-occurrences-of-substring-in-string-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. Instead of only checking `m.find()` once with a ternary if-statement, you should wrap it into a loop. Something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(matchWord + "\\W+(\\w+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()){
  words.add(m.group(1));
}
return words;
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##vZHBT8IwFMbv@yu@7LQJNqLRw1AST2gihsiBg/NQtgqd7dZ0HYMY/vbZdYPEEK@mSfv6vt9L3/ua0S29zNKvpuFSFdogswlSGS7Ixdg7y2m2ZrtW8RJByxIzyvNvD1DVSvAEpaHGHtuCp5BWChZG83z9/gEathjwwktz32UnqAudlnhAznZmaePAx@j6BtEUTxxUCMwjx@AZVFqqBs9dMy2yYUJBMkSvoKsEV/@yojfc3nXRFHPBaMnG/hB@NPXDsRtwsS8Nk6SoDFF2SiOOJpCssIb4sLibO3QFB@/MvV8WnazpEpbRQ/SxpCbZtGKIztw5NYbpHMp62sckKaTiggUnGAP4cbwcBHFcD8Jj27NWZhrSlioiu1tgX@v1P/6txqPWdO/USdCz9cY9SD55ngZh//HoqghNUyutdVGpYBT2FQe3a2Yq273jnDfwDk3zAw)