# Character length finding on string

Tags: java

Can anyone help me to write code that find how many characters string has.

Comment: Solution here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767759/occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string) Please search before you ask your next question. Regards

Comment: @Nyunus Why cant you write a simple for loop for this?

Comment: @RamanShrivastava How pls help me

Comment: @Nyunus Posted one answer. Plz check.

Comment: @Nyunus So your question is entirely changed now. You just need string length?

Comment: @RamanShrivastava yes just length can you pls edit code below like

Comment: @Nyunus Already did. Check again.

Comment: @RamanShrivastava thank u very much. By the way do you have facebook account I have just very small things to ask

Comment: posted in my answer.

Comment: @RamanShrivastava I wrote to you can u pls check on there

Answer (score 1):

All you need is - `int len = yourString.length();`

Comment: this is ok but this is not exactly what I look for. Can you pls edit this with different way if you know?

Comment: @Nyunus Can you provide one example of input and output. I will edit it accordingly.

Comment: yes just length I am new in programming can you pls edit

Comment: This is your answer..

Answer (score 0):

StringUtils should provide you with something that you are looking for:

```
       int count = StringUtils.countMatches("haahaahaa", "a");
       System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: So just for a small task like this you will add 3rd party jar?

Comment: The person who asked the question did not ask for an algorithm here and I don't see a reason why you need to reinvent the wheel everytime. Assume that for such common functions apache thought what sort of standard utils to provide.

Comment: This isn't the answer any more.. Nyunus edited his question