# Pattern regex to find tab java

Tags: java, regex

I have a statement as follows:

```
String n =
\ul\insrsid14762702 Symptom}{\insrsid14762702\ul\insrsid14762702 Acid}{\insrsid14762702\ul\insrsid14762702 Nonacid}{\insrsid14762702\ul\insrsid14762702 All}{\insrsid14762702 
 Reg\tab 100%\tab 100%\tab 100%
 Stg pain\tab 100%\tab 83%\tab 100%
 F pain\tab 72%\tab 0%\tab 67%
```

I would like to see how many tabs there are but I always get zero returned for the size of the arrayList I thought I was adding to. 
My code:

```
Pattern patternTabs = Pattern.compile("\\tab",Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcherTabs = patternTabs.matcher(n);

//Add the values between each tab.
ArrayList<String> colValue = new ArrayList<String>();

int count = 0;
while (matcherTabs.find())
    colValue.add(matcher.group());
count++;

System.out.println("ffffffffffffff"+colValue.size());
```

I have tried `\\\\tab` `\tab` `tab` all other permutations with brackets but no joy.

Comment: [Occurrences of substring in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/767759)

Comment: Are you trying to find `tab` word or `\t` space character ?

Comment: @Sebastian, When asking about whitespace, some reproducible demo at, say, ideone.com, would be really helpful. Or at least the code that can be copy/pasted into the IDE. It is very helpful in general, but is extremely helpful when whitespace is the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A literal backslash in a regex requires *4* backslashes in the String literal (2 for regex, doubled again for java), so your regex should be:

```
"\\\\tab"
```

But your other "problem" is too much code; just use `split()`:

```
String[] colValues = n.split("\\\\tab");
```