# Iterating over a string array

Tags: java, arrays, string

Return true if the string "cat" and "dog" appear the same number of times in the given string.

catDog("catdog") → true

catDog("catcat") → false

catDog("1cat1cadodog") → true

```
public boolean catDog(String str) {
  int countCat=0;
  int countDog=0;

  for(int i=0;i<str.length()-3;i++){
    if(str.substring(i).startsWith("cat")){
      countCat++;
    }
    if(str.substring(i).startsWith("dog")){
      countDog++;
    }
  }
  if(countCat==countDog){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

I am having trouble writing this method. Does anybody know why my code doesn't work correctly?
Edit: The code compiles, however it gives the wrong output. For example if i put in "catdog" it returns false.

Comment: Have you checked, that you iterate the correct amount of times? Because you currently don't.

Comment: I got it, I got it. I was working with substring(i,i+3) and forgot to change the length of iteration steps when I started using startsWith.

Answer (score 1):

with the examples you posted, its because of your for loop which should be `for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){`. you can also use str.length()-1 and str.length()-2 to get the right result. -3 will give the wrong result. little example: string is catdog1dog. result should be false. lets have a look at the substring which will be created with -3:

```
catdog1dog
atdog1dog
tdog1dog
dog1dog
og1dog
g1dog
1dog
```

as you can see with -3 the last substring is wrong and therefore the result too. that is because if you look at substring, you will see that the start is at char 0 and not at 1 therefore `str.length()-1` is the last character in your string. sorry if my explanations isn't that good

Comment: Thanks, i was working with substring(i,i+3) before and forgot to change it.

Answer (score 0):

As suggestsed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767759/occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string), I would recomment using [StringUtils.countMatches](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) from Apache Commons Lang?

Credit to @A_M

Answer (score 0):

Although your problem can be solved through other strategies, I think you might only subtract 2 to **str.length()** instead of 3.

I hope be useful!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
public boolean catDog(String str){
    return countWords(str, "cat") == countWords(str, "dog");
}


private int countWords(String original, String word){
    int counter = 0;
    boolean searching = true;
    while(searching){
        if(original.indexOf(word) >= 0){
            counter++;
            original = original.substring(original.indexOf(word) + word.length());
        }
        else{
            searching = false;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```