# Split a String using split function to count number of "that"

Tags: java, split-function

```
String str = "ABthatCDthatBHthatIOthatoo";     
System.out.println(str.split("that").length-1);
```

From this I got 4. that is right but if last that doesn't have any letter after it then it shows wrong answer '3' as in :

```
String str = "ABthatCDthatBHthatIOthat";
System.out.println(str.split("that").length-1);
```

I want to count the occurrence of "that" word in given String.

Comment: You have the same `str` for both situations and you're claiming that the output is different?

Comment: *but if last that doesn't have any letter after it* improvised the question based on it.

Comment: No, In first it is "ABthatCDthatBHthatIOthatoo" and in 2nd, "ABthatCDthatBHthatIOthat" @pedromss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could specify a limit to account for the final 'empty' token

```
System.out.println(str.split("that", -1).length-1);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/770069/1746118

Comment: Please explain reason of putting -1 here, ("that", -1) @Reimeus

Comment: All explained in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) _If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length_ i.e. don't discard empty tokens

Answer (score 3):

> str.split("that").length doesn't count the number of 'that's . It counts the
> number of *words that have 'that' in between them*

For example-

```
class test
{
 public static void main(String args[]) 
 {
     String s="Hi?bye?hello?goodDay";
     System.out.println(s.split("?").length); 
 }
}
```

This will return 4, which is the number of words separated by "?".
If you return length-1, in this case, it will return 3, which is the correct count of the number of question marks.

> **But**, what if the String is : "Hi????bye????hello?goodDay??"; **?**

Even in this case, str.split("?").length-1 will return 3, which is the incorrect count of the number of question marks.

**The actual functionality** of str.split("that //or anything") is to make a String array which has all those characters/words separated by 'that' (in this case).**The split() function returns a String array**

So, the above str.split("?") will actually return a String array : {"Hi,bye,hello,goodDay"}

str.split("?").length is returning nothing but the length of the array which has all the words in str separated by '?' .

***str.split("that").length is returning nothing but the length of the array which has all the words in str separated by 'that' .***

Here is my link for the solution of the problem [link](https://ideone.com/n8d59p)

Please tell me if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String fullStr = "ABthatCDthatBHthatIOthatoo";
String that= "that";
System.out.println(StringUtils.countMatches(fullStr, that));
```

use StringUtils from apache common lang, this one https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#line.170

Comment: you might want to detail what `StringUtils` is, its not self explanatory.

Comment: use StringUtils from apache common lang, this one https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#line.170

Comment: Update that in your answer and not in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Find out position of substring "that" using lastIndexOf() and if its at last position of the string then increment the cout by 1 of your answer.

Comment: `indexOf()` returns the index of the first occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this would help

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 


{   int count = 0;
        String str = "ABthatCDthatBHthatIOthat"; 
        StringBuffer sc = new StringBuffer(str);

    while(str.contains("that")){

        int aa = str.indexOf("that");
        count++;
        sc = sc.delete(aa, aa+3);
        str = sc.toString();


    }

    System.out.println("count is:"+count);


 }
```