# Integer cannot be converted to boolean using "indexOf()"

Tags: java

I'm trying to count how many times the word "ing" occurred in a string asked by a user, I'm having an error saying it cannot be converted.

I tried using s.indexOf("ing")

```
package javaapplication3;

import java.util.*;

public class JavaApplication3 {


public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s,q = null;
    String i = "ing";
    int count=0;
  System.out.println("Entrer une ligne de texte :");
  s = in.next();
  if ( s.indexOf("ing") ){
      count++;
  q = s.replaceAll("ing", "ed");
  }
  System.out.println("\"ing\" est occuree " +count +" fois.");
  System.out.println(q);
}
}
```

I expect the output would give me and count how many times it occurred but I'm having an error.

Comment: I think you want `if(s.indexOf("ing") != -1) { ... }` or `if(s.contains("ing")) { ... }`

Comment: `indexOf` returns an `int`, not a `boolean`.

Comment: use s.contains..

Comment: @ShubhDixit s.contais or s.indexOf() isn't counting all the word, it is giving me only the first time "ing" occurred.
Any idea?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767759/occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string

Comment: `int count = in.split("ing").length - 1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Occurrences of substring in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767759/occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `s = in.nextLine();` rather than `next()` to read the whole line
2. You need to count until the `lookFor` part is still in the word, each time replace the first occurence by something else, and continue using a while loop

   ```
   String lookFor = "ing";
   while (s.indexOf(lookFor) != -1) {
       count++;
       s = s.replaceFirst(lookFor, "ed");
   }
   ```

   same as

   ```
   String lookFor = "ing";
   while (s.contains(lookFor)) {
       count++;
       s = s.replaceFirst(lookFor, "ed");
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should `loop` over your input till your string does not have the required literal available,

```
int count = 0;
while (s.indexOf("ing") != -1) {
    s = s.replaceFirst("ing", "");
    count++;
}
System.out.print("Total occurances : "+count);
```