# how to find in java string case incesitive number of word java

Tags: java, string, comparison, case-insensitive

skdoakdoakdoakdpoakdpoakdopkapodkoapdkpoakdpoakdpakpdkapdkpaodkpakdpakdpakdpkpdkadpkapdkpaooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
dksaodaodddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddsdkaopdkpadpaokdakdopakdpakpda
dksaopdoapkdpakdpoakdpokdkapodpadpakdpoakdopakdopkpoakdpapdkapdpada
kdposaodpadpakdopakdpoakdpokpdkpakdopadkpakdkdkpadkakdpakdp

```
       String test1 = "java java java. JAVA! ";
       String test2 = "h w !!! ...";
       String word ="java";
       int count = 0;

      String strArray[] = test2.split(" ");

      for(int i=0; i < strArray.length; i++){
            if (word.equals("java")) {
                `enter code here`   
                 count++;
            }            
            System.out.println(strArray[i]);
      }

    System.out.println(count);
    test1.toUpperCase() + test1.toLowerCase().concat;
    count++;
    test1.toLowerCase();
    count++;
    System.out.println(count);
```

how to return the occurrences in java case insensitive in java i would been trolling the internet but no luck. In JavaScript i would use are but here i am new so please help. So i need to find as above suggested how many times java case insensitive occurs

Comment: See if this helps.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767759/occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string.  Only change "lastIndex = str.indexOf(findStr,lastIndex);" to "lastIndex = str.toLowerCase().indexOf(findStr,lastIndex);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hopefully this helps

```
String inputString = "java java java. JAVA!";

        int counter = 0;
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("JAVA");
        Matcher match = pattern.matcher(inputString.toUpperCase());
        while (match.find()) {
            counter++;
        }

        System.out.println(counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here:
    String regex = "JAVA";
    String input =  "Java java JAVA ss".toUpperCase();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    int count = 0;
    List<Integer> index = new ArrayList<>();
    while (m.find()) {
        count++;
        System.out.println("Match number: " + count);
        System.out.println("start: " + m.start());
        System.out.println("end: " + m.end());

        index.add(m.start());
    }
    System.out.println("count: " + count);
    System.out.println("index: " + index.toString());
```

*The first time I use this, I hope it can help you.*

Answer (score 0):

For good order:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("java", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
    int count = (int) matcher.results().count();
```

Or short:

```
    int count = Pattern.compile("java", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
            .matcher(inputString).results().count();
```