# a^2nb^n regular expression to accept twice iteration of one character over other in Java?

Tags: java, regex

Suppose my program only accepts the strings `a^2nb^n` (it can only accept the string with letter "a" repeating twice as amount to letter "b" i.e (`aab`, `aaaabb`, etc).

How can this be implemented in Java?

Comment: so if i can understand you are using just a and b what about c d e?

Comment: "_How this can be implemented in Java?_" This is a bit light, have you tried something ? We usually don't implements a solution from scratch.

Comment: This question may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763970/find-occurrences-of-characters-in-a-java-string

Comment: I don't know java programming, but I find it ridiculous that people try to use regexes and what not to solve a simple counting problem for anon-regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

You may adapt the solution from the [How can we match a^n b^n with Java regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644266)

```
^(?:aa(?=(?:aa)*(\1?+b)))+\1$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xVSogi/1). Here, the `a` is replaced with `aa` and `a*` with `(?:aa)*` (a non-capturing group matching 0+ double `a`s) to make it work for the current scenario.

[Java test](http://ideone.com/O3s9Nf):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("ab","aabb","aaaabbbb","aab","aaaabb");
for (String str : strs)
    System.out.println(str + ": " + str.matches("(?:aa(?=(?:aa)*(\\1?+b)))+\\1"));
```

Output:

```
ab: false
aabb: false
aaaabbbb: false
aab: true
aaaabb: true
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is an useful answer. It's not me who downvoted. I'm glad you helped.

Answer (score 1):

The first 2/3 of an accepted string contains "a"´s and the last 1/3 "b"´s. So you can use a regex like "a{x,y}b{x,y}" where x is the min accurance and y the max.

```
String str = "aaaabb";            
int n = str.length();             
String regex = "a{"+(n*2/3)+"}b{"+(n/3)+"}";
System.out.println(str.matches(regex));
```

Comment: What's the difference in using just 
String regex = " a{"+(n*2/3)+"}b{"+(n/3)+"} " ;

Comment: No difference. I just did not think about it correctly. Your regex is shorter and more readable. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: This is not just regex, it relies on code, and, e.g. won't be possible to use in cases where code is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```
String str = "aab";
String spl[] = str.replace("ab", "a-b").split("-");
boolean check = spl[0].matches("a+") && spl[1].matches("b+") 
                          && spl[0].length() == 2 * spl[1].length();
```

The result of split is :

```
[aa, b]
```

The idea is :

1. replace the `ab` with `a-b`
2. split with `-`, the result should look like [aaaa, bb]
3. test if the `spl[0]` contain only a and `spl[1]` contain only b if yes compare between the `spl[0]` and `spl[1]` lenght

## Ideone demo

Comment: yes it work a mistake i was checking with spl[0] and spl[0] i edit it just right now @SanketMakani