# Count of of characters matched in sequence of two string

Tags: java, android

I want to match two string  and get how many chars matched in sequence. 
Like :

```
String one="ABCDEFGHIJK";
String two="ZANDEFGHOPQ";
```

like you can see that it must return 5 chars in sequence matched because **DEFGH** are exist on both sequence.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way to count character occurrences in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100712/simple-way-to-count-character-occurrences-in-a-string)

Comment: @PratikTank i have checked this one but the problem is it is count only single charter which user must know, It is not fulfill my need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find occurrences of characters in a Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763970/find-occurrences-of-characters-in-a-java-string)

Comment: Who has down voted my question , Please dnt do this again without reading the question. 
I am not new to stack overflow i know how to ask question and after research i have come here , Please read the question carefully i have mention a word "in sequence"

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String one="ABCDEFGHIJK";
String two="ZANDEFGHOPQ";
int cnt=0;
   for (int i=0;i<one.length();i++){
       for (int j=0;j<two.length();j++){
            if(one.charAt(i) == two.charAt(j) ){
                cnt++;
            }
        }
    }

Toast.makeText(this, "count"+cnt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this will do it.

```
String one="ABCDEFGHIJK";
String two="ZANDEFGHOPQ";
int counter = 0;

// Iterate over the string character by character - stop when reaching the
// end of the shortest string
for( int i=0; i<one.length() && i<two.length(); i++ ) {
    // Compare the strings character at the current position/index
    if(one.charAt(i) == two.charAt(i)) {
        // The characters matched so increment the counter
        counter++;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class happy {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String one="ABCDEFGHIJK";
        String two="ZANDEFGHOPQ";
        int a=0,c=0;
        if(one.length()<two.length())
            a=one.length();
        else
            a=two.length();
        for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
        {
            if(one.charAt(i)==(two.charAt(i)))
                c++;
        }
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String one="ABCDEFGHIJK";
    String two="ZANDEFGHOPQ";
    int size1 = one.length();
    int size2 = two.length();
    int i = 0;
    int j = (size1 >= size2 ? size2 : size1);
    char[] oneTab = one.toCharArray();
    char[] twoTab = two.toCharArray();
    int k = 0;
    for(i = 0; i< j; i++){
        if((String.valueOf(oneTab[i])).equals(String.valueOf(twoTab[i]))){
            k = k+1;
        };
    };
    System.out.println(k);      
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a rather old question, but perhaps someone will find this "if-less" answer a nice one. One can shorten it a bit further by replacing *len* in the loop by its definition.

```java
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String one = "ABCDEFGHIJK";
        String two = "ZANDEFGHOPQ";
        int len = Math.min(one.length(), two.length());
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            counter += (one.charAt(i) == two.charAt(i)) ? 1 : 0;
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```