# count the occurrences of a specific character in the input

Tags: java, char

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I count the number of occurrences of a char in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string)

I am looking to count the occurrences of a specific character, for example "i" that occurs in the input.

Example, from standard input:
`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.`

This returns `6`, because there are 6 occurrences of the letter "i" (case matters).

This could be accomplished with a loop stepping through the string with `charAt(i)`.

Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: Whats not elegant about this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically the same as stepping through a string, but you could create a method like so:

```
private int substrCount(string findStr, string str)
{
    lastIndex = 0;
    count = 0;
    while(lastIndex != -1){
        lastIndex = str.indexOf(findStr, lastIndex);

        if(lastIndex != -1){
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is more neat: public int countCharOccurrence(String string, char countChar){
        int count = 0;
        for(int i =0; i<string.length(); i++){
            if(string.charAt(i) == countChar){
                count++;
            }
        }       
        return count;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Bet you could loop over the results of `String.indexOf()`, specifically the two input form, where you can tell it to start looking at the location of the last match.