# Remove characters from a String in Java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to remove the `.xml` part of a file name with the following code:

```
String id = fileR.getName();
              id.replace(".xml", "");
              idList.add(id);
```

The problem is that it is not removing it and I have no clue why it won't remove the target text.

***EDIT***: Actually I realize that the replace function won't find the `.xml`, so I guess the question is, how do I get rid of those last 4 characters?

Here is the string that is being passed in:

`0b14d501a594442a01c6859541bcb3e8164d183d32937b851835442f69d5c94e.xml`

Thanks,

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576352/java-remove-all-occurances-of-char-from-string

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Strings in java are immutable.  That means you need to create a new string or overwrite your old string to achieve the desired affect:

```
id = id.replace(".xml", "");
```

Comment: `replace` does **not** accept regular expressions, therefore you should not escape the `.`. `replaceAll` **does** accept regular expressions, however.

Answer (score 11):

Can't you use

```
id = id.substring(0, id.length()-4);
```

And what Eric said, ofcourse.

Comment: This assumes that he expects `.xml` to be at the end of the string (probable, though not stated).

Comment: That's why I stated the question ^.^ But, ofcourse, Eric's answer seems prettier.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable, so when you manipulate them you need to assign the result to a string:

```
String id = fileR.getName();
id = id.replace(".xml", ""); // this is the key line
idList.add(id);
```

Answer (score 2):

`String`s are immutable.  Therefore `String.replace()` does not modify `id`, it returns a new `String` with the appropriate value.  Therefore you want to use `id = id.replace(".xml", "");`.

Answer (score 1):

```
String id = id.substring(0,id.length()-4)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will safely remove only if token is at end of string.

```
StringUtils.removeEnd(string, ".xml");
```

> [Apache StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) functions are null-, empty-, and no match- safe

Comment: 8 years later..... also StringUtils is from Apache? Not native Java... should probably specify that

Comment: Added doc link. It should be implied, native doesn't contain any Util. This is a safer, more complete answer than any of the others

Comment: Wasn't saying it wasn't implied... I was saying that it was not as helpful because you didn't specify where to find the function... but the doc link definitely clears that up 

Answer (score 0):

### Kotlin Solution

Kotlin has a built-in function for this, `removeSuffix` ([Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/remove-suffix.html))

```
var text = "filename.xml"
text = text.removeSuffix(".xml") // "filename"
```

If the suffix does not exist in the string, it just returns the original

```
var text = "not_a_filename"
text = text.removeSuffix(".xml") // "not_a_filename"
```

You can also check out [`removePrefix`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/remove-prefix.html) and [`removeSurrounding`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/remove-surrounding.html) which are similar

Answer (score 0):

Java strings are immutable. But you has many options:

You can use:

The StringBuilder class instead, so you can remove everything you want and control your string.

The replace method.

And you can actually use a loop £: