# How to use replace(char, char) to replace all instances of character b with nothing

Tags: java, replace

How do i use [replace(char, char)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) to replace all instances of character "b" with nothing.

**For example:**

```
Hambbburger to Hamurger
```

**EDIT:** Constraint is only JDK 1.4.2, meaning no overloaded version of replace!

Comment: You can't as 'nothing' isn't a char! Why can't you use `replace(String,String)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: remove all occurances of char from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576352/java-remove-all-occurances-of-char-from-string)

Comment: Hi Dogbane, that is for Java 5 and above, which there will not be an overloaded version available for 1.4.2.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's also a [replaceAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) function that uses strings, note however that it evals them as regexes, but for replacing a single char will do just fine.

Here's an example:

```
String meal = "Hambbburger";

String replaced = meal.replaceAll("b","");
```

Note that the `replaced` variable is necessary since `replaceAll` doesn't change the string in place but creates a new one with the replacement (`String` is immutable in java).

If the character you want to replace has a different meaning in a regex (e.g. the `.` char will match any char, not a dot) you'll need to `quote` the first parameter like this:

```
String meal = "Ham.bur.ger";

String replaced = meal.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("."),"");
```

Comment: @Sean, I missed the function name the first time and then edit it :)

Comment: why did you change your answer? String.replace() is better!

Comment: There's already an good answer about `String#replace` (@MByD), I'll leave this because the `replace` overload is java6 and greater only

Comment: (@Pablo Fernandex) Is there strictly a way to use only replace(char, char) to achieve this?

Comment: @Pablo didn't see the requirements. java 1.4.x : bummer. I'd go looking for another job :-)

Comment: @Sean, no worries man, that last sentence wasn't part of the original question :)

Answer (score 6):

Strings are immutable, so make sure you assign the result to a string.

```
String str = "Hambbburger";
str = str.replace("b", "");
```

You don't need replaceAll if you use Java 6. See here: [replace](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: I __knew__ there was a `replace` overload!

Answer (score 3):

Try this code....

```
public class main {
public static void main(String args[]){
    String g="Hambbburger.i want to eat Hambbburger. ";
    System.out.print(g);
    g=g.replaceAll("b", "");



      System.out.print("---------After Replacement-----\n");
      System.out.print(g);

}
}
```

**output**

Hambbburger.i want to eat Hambbburger. ---------After Replacement-----
Hamurger.i want to eat Hamurger.

Answer (score 2):

```
String text = "Hambbburger";
text = text.replace('b', '\0');
```

The `'\0'` represents NUL in ASCII code.

Comment: @Tom It prints Hamurger.

Comment: Then your console prints it differently than mine, because my console explicitly shows the `\0` characters (can't show it here, since SO removes them). So this solution might depends on the system where it will be run. Strange.

Comment: The answer should be removed because it is wrong  `'\000'` does not represent nothing but the NUL character.  Check the length of `text` before and after the replacement! It hasn't changed.

Comment: @GuidoFlohr Edited answer. It is true that the length didn't change and those NULs still exist. But it does the trick for what OP asked.

Comment: @Andrew The OP asked to replace with *nothing* but a NUL byte is not nothin but just sometimes that looks like nothing (and there are a lot more unprintable characters than NUL, for example "\u200b" aka zero-width space).  Add  "System.out.println(text)" to your code, redirect the output to a file and open it in vi/vim.  You will read "Ham^A^A^Aurger" because a NUL byte is CTRL-A.  The original poster clearly meant "delete the b's" and your code does not do that.  Sorry, if that sounds rude but your answer is confusing for beginners and really not helpful.

Comment: "... sometimes that looks ..." -> "... sometimes looks ..."

Answer (score 0):

`replaceAll` in String doesnot work properly .It's Always recomend to use `replace()`

**Ex:-**

```
String s="abcdefabcdef";
s=s.replace("a","");
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. replaceAll is fine, not sure where you are getting that from - do you have a specific buggy case to hand? Also you do not answer the question - the OP wants to *remove* a character, whereas there's no way to do this with replace(char, char).

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str="aabbcc";
    int n=str.length();
    char ch[]=str.toCharArray();

    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(ch[i]==ch[j])
            {
               ch[j]='*';
            }
        }
    }
    String temp=new String(ch);

    for(int i=0;i<temp.length();i++)
    {
        if(temp.charAt(i)!='*')
        System.out.print(temp.charAt(i));
    }
```

Comment: You can also change the position of same character. This code will also work.