# Check if value has no digits, if so replace with 'Invalid' with shorthand Java

Tags: java, regex, talend

If a string has no digits in it, I would like to replace it with "Invalid" using Java (shorthand); this is to be an expression in the tMap component in Talend Open Studio

Here are some examples of desired outcomes:

Here are valid entries that should stay the same and remain unchanged, they are valid:

1. `"1234"`
2. `"123-456-7890"`
3. `"(123) 456-7890"`

Here are some values that are to replaced with "Invalid":

1. `"asdf"`
2. `"(xxx) xxx-xxxx"`
3. `"() -() -()"`
4. `"***-***-****"`
5. `"- -"`

Here's what I've tried so far:

`myTable.myField.replaceAll("[0-9]","").isEmpty() ? "Invalid" : myTable.myField`

But it's not working out, at least not in Talend

Comment: you have to set it so something: `myTable.myField = myTable.myField.replaceAll("[0-9]","").length() == 0 ? "Invalid" : myTable.myField;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013590/how-to-use-replacechar-char-to-replace-all-instances-of-character-b-with-noth

Check this out, it may help

Comment: `isEmpty()` is shortcut for `length() == 0`. To improve your question provide examples of input and expected output.

Comment: From your examples seems that you are looking for `replaceAll("^[^0-9]+$", "invalid")` which is part of @JoshF answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace any string that's all digits, like this:

```
myString.replaceAll("^[0-9]+$", "invalid");
```

According to comments, OP wants to replace any strings that don't have digits in them. here's the answer for that:

```
myString.replaceAll("^[^0-9]+$", "invalid");
```

Also, this will replace strings that do have some digits:

```
myString.replaceAll("^.*[0-9].*$", "invalid");
```

Comment: Strings are immutable, you need to reassign it with result of replacement.

Comment: Hi, I'm looking to replace strings that have no digits with "Invalid", not strings that are all digits

Comment: @Drewdavid `... if removing all of the digits produces an empty string` is not the same as `replace strings that have no digits with "Invalid"`. Which one is it?

Comment: @Drewdavid  I answered the question you wrote, but if you want all strings to contain at least one digit use this : ^.*[0-9].*$ : sorry, the question just wasn't clear

Comment: @Pshemo good spot, I fixed it. I think this is what he wants now.

Comment: @Drewdavid Are any of these what you're looking for? Ex: 1) replaces "1234", 2) replaces "asdf" but not "asdf1", and 3) replaces "asdf1" but not "asdf"

Comment: Hi, thanks I updated my question with examples to help make it more clear :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to set it so something:

```
myTable.myField = myTable.myField.replaceAll("[0-9]","").length() == 0 ? "Invalid" : myTable.myField;
```

However in this case I would use an if statement:

```
if (myTable.myField.replaceAll("[0-9]","").length() == 0){
    myTable.myField = new String("Invalid");
}
```

Comment: `isEmpty()` does the same thing as `length() == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a very simple `Pattern` for that?

For instance:

```
String foo = "abc123";
String bar = "abcdef";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d");
System.out.println(p.matcher(foo).find());
System.out.println(p.matcher(bar).find());
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

So in your case:

```
if (p.matcher(myTable.myField).find()) {
    // I'm just making the method "setText" up - replace with actual method
    myTable.myField.setText("Invalid");
}
```