# How to remove special characters from a string?

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove special characters like:

```
- + ^ . : ,
```

from an String using Java.

Comment: The phrase "special character" is so overused to be almost completely meaningless.  If what you mean is, "I have this list of **specific** characters I want to remove," then do as Thomas suggests and form your pattern with a regex character class and `replaceAll` them away.  If you have more esoteric requirements, edit the question. :)

Comment: those are not special characters...
these are: äâêíìéè since they're not your common 1-byte character types like - + ^ are...
anyway, as Ray stated, either do a `replaceAll` for them, or, do a parse on the string, add the chars that are not the chars you want to take out to another string and in the end just do a += to a String you'll be returning.

Comment: `deleteChars.apply( fromString, "-+^.:," );` – [find deleteChars here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576352/remove-all-occurrences-of-char-from-string/56916146#56916146)

Answer (score 291, accepted):

That depends on what you define as special characters, but try `replaceAll(...)`:

```
String result = yourString.replaceAll("[-+.^:,]","");
```

Note that the `^` character must not be the first one in the list, since you'd then either have to escape it or it would mean "any but these characters".

Another note: the `-` character needs to be the first or last one on the list, otherwise you'd have to escape it or it would define a range ( e.g. `:-,` would mean "all characters in the range `:` to `,`).

So, in order to keep consistency and not depend on character positioning, you might want to escape all those characters that have a special meaning in regular expressions (the following list is not complete, so be aware of other characters like `(`, `{`, `$`  etc.):

```
String result = yourString.replaceAll("[\\-\\+\\.\\^:,]","");
```

If you want to get rid of all punctuation and symbols, try this regex: `\p{P}\p{S}` (keep in mind that in Java strings you'd have to escape back slashes: `"\\p{P}\\p{S}"`).

A third way could be something like this, if you can exactly define what should be left in your string:

```
String  result = yourString.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s]","");
```

This means: replace everything that is not a word character (a-z in any case, 0-9 or _) or whitespace.

Edit: please note that there are a couple of other patterns that might prove helpful. However, I can't explain them all, so have a look at the reference section of [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html).

Here's less restrictive alternative to the "define allowed characters" approach, as suggested by Ray:

```
String  result = yourString.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Z}]","");
```

The regex matches everything that is not a letter in any language and not a separator (whitespace, linebreak etc.). Note that you can't use `[\P{L}\P{Z}]` (upper case P means not having that property), since that would mean "everything that is not a letter or not whitespace", which almost matches everything, since letters are not whitespace and vice versa.

*Additional information on Unicode*

Some unicode characters seem to cause problems due to different possible ways to encode them (as a single code point or a combination of code points). Please refer to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html) for more information.

Comment: +1 for the best general-purpose solution.  Since you are listing a couple variations in the absence of details from the OP, you might as well show and explain patterns like `[\P{L}]`

Comment: Also note that the `-` character must be the first or last one in the list or it needs to be escaped.

Comment: `[^\\p{L}\\p{Z}]` seems to eliminate German Umlauts (ä,ö,ü) as well (at least it does so for me:/), so  "The regex matches everything that is not a letter in any language" doesn't seem to be 100% correct

Comment: @Peter it doesn't eliminate those characters in my tests. There might be another problem in your case, e.g. a different encoding of the text. I'll add a link to more information.

Comment: @Thomas `String  result = yourString.replaceAll("[^\w\s]","");` makes error `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`

Comment: @VisruthCV you'd need to escape the backslashes in Java strings, i.e. use `"[^\\w\\s]"`. I'll fix that error in my answer as well.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks. I have optimized your answer   youredittextvariable.setText((youredittextvariable.getText().toString().replaceAll("[″&<>′]","")).toString());  for android.

Comment: yourString.replaceAll String.replaceAll() method not resolved in Kotlin. Any solution?

Comment: @blackjack well, a quick search for "Kotlin replace all string" came up with this as one of the first results: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/replace.html - It seems `replace(regex, replacement)` would be the method to use.

Answer (score 69):

This will replace all the  characters except alphanumeric

```
replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]","");
```

Comment: This will remove arabic characters as well.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: Why in my case this special character ^ it’s not removed?

Answer (score 18):

As described here
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

> Patterns are compiled regular expressions. In many cases, convenience methods such as `String.matches`, `String.replaceAll` and `String.split` will be preferable, but if you need to do a lot of work with the same regular expression, it may be more efficient to compile it once and reuse it. The Pattern class and its companion, Matcher, also offer more functionality than the small amount exposed by String.

```
public class RegularExpressionTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("String is = "+getOnlyStrings("!&(*^*(^(+one(&(^()(*)(*&^%$#@!#$%^&*()("));
    System.out.println("Number is = "+getOnlyDigits("&(*^*(^(+91-&*9hi-639-0097(&(^("));
}

 public static String getOnlyDigits(String s) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    String number = matcher.replaceAll("");
    return number;
 }
 public static String getOnlyStrings(String s) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-z A-Z]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    String number = matcher.replaceAll("");
    return number;
 }
}
```

Result

```
String is = one
Number is = 9196390097
```

Comment: This will remove arabic characters

Answer (score 15):

Try `replaceAll()` method of the `String` class.

BTW here is the method, return type and parameters.

```
public String replaceAll(String regex,
                         String replacement)
```

Example:

```
String str = "Hello +-^ my + - friends ^ ^^-- ^^^ +!";
str = str.replaceAll("[-+^]*", "");
```

It should remove all the {'^', '+', '-'} chars that you wanted to remove!

Answer (score 14):

To Remove Special character

```
String t2 = "!@#$%^&*()-';,./?><+abdd";

t2 = t2.replaceAll("\\W+","");
```

Output will be : `abdd.`

This works perfectly.

Comment: will get illegal escape character in string literal

Comment: This will also remove the spaces if you want to keep the spaces then use 

t2 = t2.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s]", "");

Answer (score 2):

Use the `String.replaceAll()` method in Java. 
[replaceAll](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) should be good enough for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove single char as follows:

```
String str="+919595354336";

 String result = str.replaceAll("\\\\+","");

 System.out.println(result);
```

OUTPUT:

```
919595354336
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do a literal replace in java, use `Pattern.quote(string)` to escape any string to a literal.

```
myString.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(matchingStr), replacementStr)
```