# Punctuation marks permissive string comparison in Java

Tags: java, android, string

I want to compare (case insensitive) two strings ignoring punctuation marks like dots, commas or other symbols (like spanish or french letters `ó ü ê` etc)

Some examples:

```
  Hello == Helló
  Hello, Sam == Hello sam
  geo-code   == geocode == geo code
```

(Is not necessary to cover all the options)

Whats the best solution (external libraries, methods, etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove all special characters.

Like from `geo-code` remove `-` it becomes `geocode`. Similarly, remove space from `geo code`

`Hello, sam` after removing space and comma becomes `Hellosam` then you can compare these strings. [Here's how you can do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7552284/1581147)

Now about the special characters like French ones: [This will help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008802/converting-symbols-accent-letters-to-english-alphabet)

Here's the [code found in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1215117/1581147). I have not tested it.

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public String deAccent(String str) {
    String nfdNormalizedString = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD); 
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
    return pattern.matcher(nfdNormalizedString).replaceAll("");
}
```