# Remove Special Characters For A Pattern Java

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I want to remove that characters from a String:

```
+ - ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ ~ : \
```

also I want to remove them:

```
/*
*/
&&
||
```

I mean that I will not remove `&` or `|` I will remove them if the second character follows the first one (`/* */ && ||`)

How can I do that efficiently and fast at Java?

Example:

```
a:b+c1|x||c*(?)
```

will be:

```
abc1|xc*?
```

Comment: Best advice?  Try it and see what works.  Don't worry about efficiency or speed.  It isn't likely to make any difference; worry about it only when it does.

Comment: What did you try? You should take a look at `String#replaceAll()`.

Comment: I want to see any trick for eliminating || but not |

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove special characters from an string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552253/how-to-remove-special-characters-from-an-string)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via a long, but actually [very simple regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

```
String aString = "a:b+c1|x||c*(?)";
String sanitizedString = aString.replaceAll("[+\\-!(){}\\[\\]^~:\\\\]|/\\*|\\*/|&&|\\|\\|", "");
System.out.println(sanitizedString);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the java.lang.String.replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) is all you need:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String).

Answer (score 0):

[Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/637853/thomas) wrote on [How to remove special characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552253/how-to-remove-special-characters-from-an-string/7552284#7552284):

> That depends on what you define as special characters, but try
>   replaceAll(...):
>
> ```
> String result = yourString.replaceAll("[-+.^:,]","");
> ```
>
> Note that the ^ character must not be the first one in the list, since
>   you'd then either have to escape it or it would mean "any but these
>   characters".
>
> Another note: the - character needs to be the first or last one on the
>   list, otherwise you'd have to escape it or it would define a range (
>   e.g. :-, would mean "all characters in the range : to ,).
>
> So, in order to keep consistency and not depend on character
>   positioning, you might want to escape all those characters that have a
>   special meaning in regular expressions (the following list is not
>   complete, so be aware of other characters like (, {, $ etc.):
>
> ```
> String result = yourString.replaceAll("[\\-\\+\\.\\^:,]","");
> ```
>
> If you want to get rid of all punctuation and symbols, try this regex:
>   \p{P}\p{S} (keep in mind that in Java strings you'd have to escape
>   back slashes: "\p{P}\p{S}").
>
> A third way could be something like this, if you can exactly define
>   what should be left in your string:
>
> ```
> String  result = yourString.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s]","");
> ```
>
> Here's less restrictive alternative to the "define allowed characters"
>   approach, as suggested by Ray:
>
> ```
> String  result = yourString.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Z}]","");
> ```
>
> The regex matches everything that is not a letter in any language and
>   not a separator (whitespace, linebreak etc.). Note that you can't use
>   [\P{L}\P{Z}] (upper case P means not having that property), since that
>   would mean "everything that is not a letter or not whitespace", which
>   almost matches everything, since letters are not whitespace and vice
>   versa.

Answer (score 0):

there is two way to do that :

1)

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList.add("+");
    arrayList.add("-");
    arrayList.add("||");
    arrayList.add("&&");
    arrayList.add("(");
    arrayList.add(")");
    arrayList.add("{");
    arrayList.add("}");
    arrayList.add("[");
    arrayList.add("]");
    arrayList.add("~");
    arrayList.add("^");
    arrayList.add(":");
    arrayList.add("/");
    arrayList.add("/*");
    arrayList.add("*/");
    String string = "a:b+c1|x||c*(?)";
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
        if (string.contains(arrayList.get(i)));
            string=string.replace(arrayList.get(i), "");
    }
    System.out.println(string);
```

2)

```
    String string = "a:b+c1|x||c*(?)";
    string = string.replaceAll("[+\\-!(){}\\[\\]^~:\\\\]|/\\*|\\*/|&&|\\|\\|", "");
    System.out.println(string);
```