# remove escape sequence character from java string

Tags: java, string, escaping, sequence

I'm having java string as

```
 "zHG\/dB0lt2Z8xrUQlbZXfRyZuvsDZZM+H5M7vHBbsEo="
```

how to remove '\' character from the abovestring

thanks in advance

Comment: replaceAll("\\", "")

Comment: tried .replaceAll("\\", ""), but hitting Unexpected internal error near index 1

Comment: look on this post please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552253/how-to-remove-special-characters-from-an-string

Comment: This cannot be a valid Java String constant, for starters

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String str = "zHG\/dB0lt2Z8xrUQlbZXfRyZuvsDZZM+H5M7vHBbsEo=";
str = str.replace("\\","");
```

Or you can use `replaceAll`

For more detail [Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576352/java-remove-all-occurrences-of-char-from-string)

Comment: Apache was tried,but hitting Unexpected internal error near index 1,see comments under question.Can you give alternate solution?