# how to replace special characters in talend integration

Tags: integration, talend

i want to replace special charecters in talend integration.
**Example Records are:**

```
id                  mrp
013SB X121MULTI     7633
013SB/X121MULTI     46696
013SBX121MULTI      8531
013SBX121MU*LTI     4939
013SBX121MULTI      1347
013SBX121MULTI      5388
013SBX121MULTI      53592
013SBX_121MULTI     449
```

**Expected Results are**

```
    id                  mrp
    013SBX121MULTI      7633
    013SBX121MULTI      46696
    013SBX121MULTI      8531
    013SBX121MULTI      4939
    013SBX121MULTI      1347
    013SBX121MULTI      5388
    013SBX121MULTI      53592
    013SBX121MULTI      449
```

special charecters contained in 1,2,4 and last record.i want to replace special charecters like (space,_,-,*,etc..,)
can anyone suggest for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use tJavaRow to clear id field. In tJavaRow you can do **everything** what Java allows you to do with these data. Firstly we need to find way to remove special chars from String. According to these [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552253/how-to-remove-special-characters-from-a-string) we can add in tJavaRow component something like this:

```
output_row.id = input_row.id.replaceAll("[^\\w]","").replaceAll("_", "");;
output_row.mrp = input_row.mrp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code should simply fulfill the requirement. In addition, it will give only an alphanumeric result excluding special characters (NOT only **space,_,-,*,etc..,**) :

```
input_row.col1.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "")
```

> This code can be either used in tJavaRow or directly into tMap