# How to remove all special character in a string except dot and comma

Tags: java, android

I have a sentence with many special characters and text in it, I want remove all the special characters except dot and comma.

For example, this is what have:

```
[u' %$HI# Jhon, $how$ are *&$%you.%$
```

I'm trying to produce the following string:

```
HI Jhon, how are you.
```

I tried this

```
("[u' %$HI# Jhon, $how$ are *&$%you.%$").replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+","");
```

But it removes commas and dots also. I want commas and dots to be there.

Finally i found solution:

Python:

```
import re

my_str = "[u' %$HI# Jhon, $how$ are *&$%you.%$"
my_new_string = re.sub('[^.,a-zA-Z0-9 \n\.]', '', my_str)
print (my_new_string)
```

Java:

```
("[u' %$HI# Jhon, $how$ are *&$%you.%$").replaceAll("[^ .,a-zA-Z0-9]");
```

Thanks all. I Don't know whats wrong with my question, Don't have freedom to ask. :-(

Comment: Define "special".

Comment: @StefanPochmann Good point. I supposed any non-alphanumerical character, but that would also remove the ability to write a question effectively.

Comment: Following edit: why not add dots and commas to the character class in your `replaceAll` of non-acceptable characters to remove?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove special characters from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552253/how-to-remove-special-characters-from-a-string)

Answer (score 6):

```
("[u' %$HI# Jhon, $how$ are *&$%you.%$").replace(/[^.,a-zA-Z]/g, '');
```

You need to add comma and dot with all characters inside the brackets, like I just did.

And you might want to include numbers too.

```
("[u' %$HI# Jhon, $how$ are *&$%you.%$").replace(/[^.,a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
```

Edited

And, as noted below, your output also needs spaces:

```
("[u' %$HI# Jhon, $how$ are *&$%you.%$").replace(/[^.,a-zA-Z ]/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

This might also help:

```
>>> punctuation = """!\"#$%&'()*+-/:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~"""
>>> string = "[%$HI# Jhon, $how$ are *&$%you.%$"
>>> edited = ""
>>> for i in string:
...     if i not in punctuation:
...         edited += i
...
>>> edited
'HI Jhon, how are you.'
```

Answer (score 0):

*assembling a new string w/o the 'special'-characters using lambda* [java]

```
String s = "[u' %$HI# John, $how$ are *&$%you.%$";
s.codePoints().mapToObj( Character::toChars ).filter(
    a -> (a.length == 1 && (Character.isLetterOrDigit( a[0] ) || Character.isSpaceChar( a[0] )
        || a[0] == '.' || a[0] == ',')) )
    .collect( StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append ).toString();
//u HI John, how are you.
```