# Removing Quotes From All Elements of a String[]

Tags: java, arrays, string, trim

I was given a text document that has 5K+ names all in caps, and all in "double quotes." I have split all the names by the commas so I have a populated String[] filled with names in quotes. I need to remove all the quotes from the names, I have tried using .trim('"') but keep getting errors.

Here is my code:

```
public class NameScore {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    //File path to name list
    String NAME_LIST = "/Users/BR/NameScores/src/p022_names.txt";


    //imports the file with names
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(NAME_LIST));

    //Array list that holds the appx. 5K names. Each name split by a comma
    String[] nameList = (input.nextLine()).split(",");
    //puts the list into alphabetical order.
    Arrays.sort(nameList);


    for (int i = 0; i < nameList.length; i++) {

        //nameList[i] = nameList[i].trim('"');
        System.out.println(nameList[i]);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: if this is a csv file then use something like csvReader to parse it.  It can automatically get rid of double quotes

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *regular expression* with [`String.replaceAll(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) like

```
System.out.println(nameList[i].replaceAll("\"", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments by @ScaryWombat, if this is a valid CSV file, you can use a CSV library ([such as opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)):

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(".../p022_names.txt"));
List<String[]> allLines = reader.readAll();

for(String[] line: allLines){
    for(String field: line){
        System.out.print(field + "\t"); 
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

CSVReader will :

- split fields between commas;
- remove the surrounding double quotes in each field.

opencsv's maven dependency
:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
    <version>3.7</version> 
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use inputString.replaceAll("[\-\+\.\^:,]","");

For more info check it: [How to remove special characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552253/how-to-remove-special-characters-from-a-string)