# how to remove country code when i paste a phone number which is copied from another resource (need to remove special chars also )?

Tags: android

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){         

   if(s.length()>10) {

       String edt = s.toString(); 
       String edtResult = edt.substring(Math.max(edt.length() - 10, 0));
       edtSearch.setText(edtResult);
   }
}
```

how can i make my edittext to enter only 10 digits num.and also need to remove country code when i paste a phone number which is copied from another resource (need to remove special characters also in that if any )and only i want to show actual 10 digits number on my edittext when i paste and enter?

and in my xml I use

`android:digits="0123456789"` for only allowing numbers. If I use
`android:setMaxLength="10"` its fine for entering only 10 digits but its not workout when I paste my number which has country code and special chars like [-] in it.

Comment: follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552253/how-to-remove-special-characters-from-a-string