# Ignore starting blank space and special character only capitalize first alphabet from string

Tags: android, string

String name1 = "       shashi";

Output: name1:"       Shashi";

String name2 = "@@@shashi";

Output: name2: = "@@@Shashi";

String name3 = "@#$&shashi";

Output: name3: = "@#$&Shashi";

Note: Capitalize only first letter of alphabet, ignore space and special character.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try this to remove Special Characters

```
 public static String getOnlyStrings(String s) {
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-z A-Z]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
String number = matcher.replaceAll("");
return number;
```

}

So your call should be

```
str = getOnlyStrings(str);
```

& then capitalized first letter using

```
str.replace(str.charAt(0),str.toUpperCase().charAt(0));
```

You may need to change the Pattern according to your needs, Current pattern only accepts Characters from a to z

Credits : [Answer: How to remove special characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32962649/8017588)

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replaceAll(" ","");
str.replace(str.charAt(0),str.toUpperCase().charAt(0));
```

hm..... if you want to ignore the special character, recommend to use ASCIICODE and charAt method.