# Removing square brackets and double quotes from ListView

Tags: json

I am building a small app that lists some books using Google book API. when I make a request I got that answer with **[** and **"**. I want to remove them

[image]

Comment: can you show us the json you are getting?

Comment: you can remove them by replacing character while setting data to TextView `Str.replace('[', '') ` you can even use Regex to replace eliminate those characters

Comment: Show your JSON FILe

Comment: Follow this URL . Hope this will help you.
Url:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552253/how-to-remove-special-characters-from-a-string

Comment: here is the json

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=android&maxResults=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the adapter You should replace each character you don't need with space like this:

```
list.get(i).getName().replace("[","");
```

For a more specific answer, please post your Jason.

**Update:**
[] in Json is JsonArray and {} is for JsonObject.
So you should parse your Jso correctly using Gson or any other library you are using.

Comment: @MohamedHamza Could you provide the code where you parse the Json?

Answer (score 1):

As in the JSON that you attached, the **object►items►0►volumeInfo►authors** is a JsonArray and same for **object►items►0►volumeInfo►categories►**

So you need to parse authors and categories into an array of Strings and display the first object of the array in your UI