# Jira REST API v2 - Task description formatting

Tags: api, rest, devops, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm using Jira REST API v2 to retrieve the task description. But the result consists of lots of garbage like `\n`, `\t` and special Jira formatting symbols. Is there any approach to format the result string into a human readable format?

Answer (score 0):

Actually isn't garbage. There are Special Character Sequences, to keep the format that user give when write in the editor. I recomend not delete it but if you want you can remove, for exaple with regex.

An example: [How to remove special characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552253/how-to-remove-special-characters-from-a-string/7552284)