# How to strip out empty/single-character parentheses in a Java string

Tags: java, regex

I want to strip out everything that is a single character inside a parenthesis. For example, in the string "I am at part (a) and not (aaa)", the desired result is "I am at part  and not (aaa)", where the second parenthesis pair is kept because it is longer. How can I accomplish this in Java? I have tried the following but it does not match anything!

```
 String text = "the meaning of 5 U.S.C. 552(a)(6)(B) and Section 1.16(b) .";
 text.replaceAll("\\(.?\\)", ""); // should return "the meaning of 5 U.S.C. 552 and Section 1.16 ." but doesn't!
```

I think the problem is how I am escaping the the backslash and parenthesis character, but I have tried numerous variations such as "\\(.?\\)" to no avail. Furthermore, they seem to work on online regular expression sites, so I am completely at lost what could be wrong.

Comment: So what *does* it currently return? Note that you're currently *ignoring* the return value - you're just calling `replaceAll`, which will not change the *existing* string, but return a new string with the replacements made. Could that be the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: remove all occurances of char from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576352/java-remove-all-occurances-of-char-from-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your regex looks fine - are you maybe forgetting to allocate the result to a variable?

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\(.?\\)", "");
```