# Split string by space and ignore periods

Tags: java, string, split

I'm trying to take in a `String` as an input, split it by the space character in order to store the words in an array, and then use those words to compare to other words. The problem is I would like for periods to be ignored during the split as the words they are being compared to will never contain a period.

For example:

```
String testString = "This. is. a. test. string.";
String[] test = testString.split(" ");

for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(test[i]);
}
```

This will print out:

```
This.
is.
a.
test.
string.
```

Instead, I would like it to print out:

```
This
is
a
test
string
```

How can I ignore the period during the split?

Comment: Does the input always come with periods like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: remove all occurances of char from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576352/java-remove-all-occurances-of-char-from-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
String[] test = testString.split("\\.[ ]*");
```

or

```
String[] test = testString.split("\\.\\s*");
```

or for more than one period (and ellipsis)

```
String[] test = testString.split("\\.+\\s*");
```

Comment: Use \s* to check for multiple spaces

Comment: Although this is no longer wrong on the example input, it was just a single example.  OP asked "I would like for periods to be ignored during the split."  I don't see how this fits that requirement.  For example, what about a sentence with an ellipsis...

Comment: @mbroshi Couldn't you just then add a `+` after the `.`?

Comment: I suppose this has become a nearly Talmudic discussion at this point.  I will remove my downvote and let the OP sort things out him/herself.

Comment: @user2310289 Thanks for the updated answers and explanation of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] test = testString.split("\\.\\s*");
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the dot inside the splitted string    `replace(".","");`

```
String testString = "This. is. a. test. string.";
      String[] test = testString.split(" ");

      for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
          System.out.println(test[i].replace(".",""));
      }}
```

Comment: Why not remove them before? Does it make a difference?

Comment: This places the "." in the String array.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String st = "This. is. a. test. string."";
        String[] tokens = st.split(".(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
        for(String t : tokens) {
            System.out.println("> "+t);
        }
    }
}
```