# How do I remove spaces in a String (sentence)

Tags: java, loops, logic, substring

I need to remove all spaces from it.

Eg: This is my code
O/P : Thisismycode

This is my code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class nospace{

public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a String");
    String N=s.nextLine();
    N=N.trim();
    N=N+" ";
    int l=N.length();
    int a=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=l-1;i++){
        if(N.charAt(i)==32){
    System.out.println(N.substring(a,i+1));
    }
    a=i;

    }

}

}
```

All it does it print the last letters of each word. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: remove all occurances of char from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576352/java-remove-all-occurances-of-char-from-string)

Answer (score 5):

you can try to us this piece of code

```
N.replaceAll("\\s+","")
```

This states that you replace all white spaces inside a string object with an empty string (""). The part `"\\s+"` is called a regex and in combination with replaceAll removes all whitespaces and non visible characters such as tab.
Also notice that  `st.replaceAll("\\s","")` produces the same result. The second regex is  faster than the first one. But we increase the number consecutive spaces, first one performs better than the second one

Comment: The general doc for replaceAll is available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: A plain `replace(" ", "")` is enough and doesn't involve regex.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using Java's string replaceAll function. You give it the regex that you're looking to replace, and what you want to replace it with:

```
string.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

So your code should look like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class nospace{

public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a String");
    String input=s.nextLine();
    input = input.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    System.out.println(input);

}

}
```

I changed your input variable from N to input - in Java you shouldn't use capital letters to start the name of a variable. Additionally, I removed some of the other lines you had, such as adding a space to the end of your input string, and creating the l and a variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something with Strings in Java,  [Commons Lang StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#remove%28java.lang.String,%20char%29) is a great place to look.

```
String newString = StringUtils.deleteWhitespace(oldStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class RemoveExtraspaces {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str="   Hello and welcome !    let's start    coding    ";
        char prev;
        char current;
        String punc="?,.!";
        String result = "";
        for(int i=1;i<str.length();i++){
            current=str.charAt(i);
            prev=str.charAt(i-1);
            if(current==' ' && prev==' ' && punc.indexOf(current)<0){
                prev=current;
            }
            else if(punc.indexOf(current)>0){
                if(prev==' ')
                    result=result.substring(0,result.length()-1);
                    result=result+current;
            }
            else {
                result=result+current;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);

    }


}
```

Comment: This is to remove extra spaces. Others are trying to remove all spaces