# The filter string - removing some chars

Tags: java

is there a function in Java which removed from a string unwanted chars given by me? If not, what the most effective way to do it. I would like realize it in JAVA

EDIT:
But, I want reach for example:

```
String toRescue="@8*"
String text = "ra@dada882da(*%"
and after call function:
string text2="@88*"
```

Comment: Have you looked at the javadoc of `String`?

Comment: Are third-party libraries fair game?  Guava's [`CharMatcher`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) lets you define and operate on character classes, e.g. `CharMatcher.anyOf("aeiou").removeFrom(string)`

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576352/java-remove-all-occurances-of-char-from-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression, for example:

```
String text  = "ra@dada882da(*%";
String text2 = text.replaceAll("[^@8*]", "");
```

After executing the above snippet, `text2` will contain the string `"@88*"`.

Answer (score 0):

The Java String has many methods which can help you, such as

```
String.replace(char old, char new);
String.split(regex);
String.substring(int beginIndex);
```

These and many others are described in the javadoc : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html