# How to remove a $ sign from a string before updating DB

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I need help on how to remove a $ signs from a string before updating DB Currently in my application the from end on default adds a $ as a first character. I need to know how I can remove that because I get the Big Decimal error when updating DB.

```
String postagePaid = (String) request.getParameter("tPostagePaid");
            String insuranceFees = (String) request.getParameter("tInsuranceFees");
            String registeredFees = (String) request.getParameter("tRegisteredFees");
            String codFees = (String) request.getParameter("tCODFees");
            String insRegisteredCODFees = (String) request.getParameter("tInsuranceFees");
            System.out.println("insurance Fee: " + insuranceFees);
            if (postagePaid != null && !insuranceFees.isEmpty()) { // postage paid amount
                claim.setClPostagePaidAmt(new BigDecimal(postagePaid));
            }
            if (insuranceFees != null && !insuranceFees.isEmpty()) { // Insurance Fees
                claim.setClInsuranceFee(new BigDecimal(insuranceFees));
            }
            if (registeredFees != null && !insuranceFees.isEmpty()) { // Registered Fees
                claim.setClRegisteredFee(new BigDecimal(registeredFees));
            }
            if (codFees != null && !insuranceFees.isEmpty()) { // COD Fees
                claim.setClCodFee(new BigDecimal(codFees));
            }
            claim.setClInsRegCodAmt(null);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576352/java-remove-all-occurrences-of-char-from-string

Comment: so what is the actual problem? did u try anything to replace like `yourStr.replaceAll("\\$","")` or anything?

Comment: Better to just do `yourStr.replace("$", "")` and avoid used regexes when they aren't needed.

Comment: @SparkOn I was trying .replace('$', '')  but it didnt work now im trying .replace("$", "")  lets see if it works.

Comment: @user2149910 does it even compiled? you really need to learn        some  basics http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try two things.

```
str = str.replace("$","");
```

OR

```
str = str.substring(1);
```

REASON
You just want to remove the first character.