# How can I relieve myself from the last character of a String variable java

Tags: java

I have string variable where at certain times the variable has "+" or "#" characters at the end of the string. I want to remove these characters from the end of the string. I wrote the following code but it doesn't work. The code compiles and the else command works but the if and if else statements do not work. Thank you for your help

```
if (konHamle.contains("+") ) 
{
    int kont1 = konHamle.indexOf("+");
    hamHamle = konHamle.substring(0, konHamle.length() - 1);
    break;
} 
else 
{
    hamHamle = konHamle;
    break;

}
```

Comment: Define _do not work_.

Comment: The solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576352/java-remove-all-occurrences-of-char-from-string might be of use to you.  Can the characters you want to remove appear anywhere else, or only at the end?

Comment: I would try `hamHamle = konHamle.substring(0, konHamle.lastIndexOf("+") - 1);`

Comment: By relieving I meant getting rid of the character... Regards..

Comment: Only at the end... Thank you

Comment: Do not work: Compiles and runs but does not produce a string if the condition is True, however the else statement works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`indexOf` gives you the first occurence, hence your code might not be working

Try regex. `$` marks the end of line, this will also handle multiple characters like `#` and `+` as mentioned in the question.

```
konHamle = konHamle.replaceAll("[#+]$", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

This is much simpler using [`String.endsWith()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith%28java.lang.String%29):

```
if (konHamle.endsWith("+")){
    konHamle = konHamle.substring(0, konHamle.length() - 1);
}
```

Or even shorter (less readable though):

```
 konHamle = konHamle.endsWith("+") ? konHamle.substring(0, konHamle.length() - 1) : konHamle;
```

Comment: I2ll check and let you know. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) method of String.

```
public String removeLastPlusMethod(String str) {
    if (str.length() > 0 && str.charAt(str.length()-1)=='+') {
      str = str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
    }
    return str;
}
```

You can also use [endsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) method to check the last character of a string.