# How to break a file into tokens based on regex using Java

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I have a file in the following format, records are separated by newline but some records have line feed in them, like below.  I need to get each record and process them separately.  The file could be a few Mb in size.

```
 <?aaaaa>
 <?bbbb
     bb>
 <?cccccc>
```

I have the code:

```
 FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(FILE_PATH_NAME);
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fs);
 scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("<\\?"));
 if (scanner.hasNext()) {
     String line = scanner.next();
     System.out.println(line);
 } 
 scanner.close();
```

But the result I got have the begining <\? removed:

```
aaaaa>
bbbb
   bb>
cccccc>
```

I know the Scanner consumes any input that matches the delimiter pattern.  All I can think of is to add the delimiter pattern back to each record mannully.

Is there a way to NOT have the delimeter pattern removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Break on a newline only when preceded by a `">"` char:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("(?<=>)\\R"); // Note you can pass a string directly
```

`\R` is a system independent newline
`(?<=>)` is a *look behind* that asserts (without consuming) that the previous char is a `>`

Plus it's cool because `<=>` looks like [Darth Vader's TIE fighter](http://www.starwars.com/databank/darth-vader-s-tie-fighter).

Comment: I tested with more records and this approach made some records on the same line.  Can you please help ?

Comment: @jlp do you mean a "missing" newline like in `"<?aaa>\n<?bbb><?ccc>\n<?ddd>"` between bbb and ccc?

Comment: btw, if that is the case it's easy to handle - just add `?` to the end of the regex

Comment: @Bohemian Hi, sorry, I have another question.  If the data is like "<aaaa><bbbb><cccc>" with no space or newline between them, how do I make my regex so that it can break them into 3 lines like <aaaa> then <bbbb> and <cccc>.  Please let me know if I should create another post for this questions.  Thanks.

Comment: @jlp as per previous comment; add `?` to the regex: `scanner.useDelimiter("(?<=>)\\R?");`. This makes the newline *optional*, but will consume it if it's there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to ignore the newline character `'\n'` everywhere.

I would read the [whole file into a `String`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-do-i-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file) and then [remove all of the `'\n'`s in the `String`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576352/remove-all-occurrences-of-char-from-string). The part of the code this question is about looks like this:

```
String fileString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
fileString = fileString.replace("\n", "");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileString);
...  //your code
```

Feel free to ask any further questions you might have!

Comment: The file may be a few Mb large, not sure if it's going to cause any issues if storing the entire file into a string.

Comment: @jlp I wouldn't worry about files being a couple of megabytes in size, but you're right that this approach wouldn't scale very well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it by using a `StringBuilder`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("C:\\test.txt"));
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    String input = null;
    while (in.hasNextLine() && null != (input = in.nextLine())) {
        for (int x = 0; x < input.length(); x++) {
            builder.append(input.charAt(x));
            if (input.charAt(x) == '>') {
                System.out.println(builder.toString());
                builder = new StringBuilder();
            }
        }
    }

    in.close();
}
```

**Input:**

```
 <?aaaaa>
 <?bbbb
     bb>
 <?cccccc>
```

**Output:**

```
 <?aaaaa>
 <?bbbb     bb>
 <?cccccc>
```