# How to remove hashtags and urls from a String

Tags: java, string

I want to remove hashtags and urls from a String.

Example:

- Before: `Cristiano Ronaldo is the #best player in the #world. https://..`
- After: `Cristiano Ronaldo is the best player in the world.`

How could this be achieved?

Comment: You should use string replace to remove the # and with regex you should be available to remove urls. When you have problems with regex or something you should ask new.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all occurrences of char from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576352/remove-all-occurrences-of-char-from-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of you should replace all hashtags with an empty String.

```
String text = "Ronaldo is the #best player in the #world. http://www.google.de";
String textWithoutHashtags = text.replace("#", "");
```

Now `textWithoutHashtags` is the initial text without unwanted hashtags.

Next you'd need to replace all urls with an empty String, which I'd recommend doing with a Regular Expression.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(http|ftp|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(textWithoutHashtags);
String textWithoutHashtagsAndUrls = matcher.replaceAll("");
```

You should probably also trim the String afterwards to remove unnecessary spaces.

```
String ready = textWithoutHashtagsAndUrls.trim();
```

Note that the Regular Expression used only works for urls which have `http://`, `https://` or `ftp://` prefixed. Removing `www.google.de` won't work.

Comment: Nice solution. And could you please tell what to do if I have to remove the whole hashtag i.e. including the word.

Comment: @RakshitBhatnagar You would need to use Regex once again. It's the same as for the URLs but with another pattern. I can recommend this site: http://regexr.com/ to learn Regex. If you need an example let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The String class have a replaceAll method which replace every occurrence of a character/regex with a defined (even empty) string. You can see the Javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

```
String tweet = "Cristiano Ronaldo is the #best player in the #world. http://www.google.com";
String tweetWithoutHash = tweet.replaceAll("#", "");
System.out.println(tweetWithoutHash); // Cristiano Ronaldo is the best player in the world. http://www.google.com
String urlPattern = "((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|Unsure|http):((//)|(\\\\))+[\\w\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*)";
String tweetWithoutHashAndUrl = tweetWithoutHash.replaceAll(urlPattern, "");
System.out.println(tweetWithoutHashAndUrl); // Cristiano Ronaldo is the best player in the world.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to remove stopWord, tags and annotation from user tweet removeStopwords (tweet), for the stop words List you must add your own List or remove this step :
`

```
public static ArrayList<String> removeStopwords (String tweet){
    ArrayList<String> wordsList = new ArrayList<String>();
     try{
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(tweet);
            String[] words = builder.toString().split("\\s");
            for (String word : words){
                wordsList.add(word.toLowerCase().trim());
            }
            wordsList.removeAll(stopwords);
            for(int ii = 0; ii < wordsList.size(); ii++){
                    String [] spl = wordsList.get(ii).split("@");
                    if (spl.length > 1){
                        wordsList.remove(ii);
                    }else {
                        String [] spl1 = wordsList.get(ii).split("#");
                        if (spl1.length > 1){
                            wordsList.remove(ii);
                        }
                    }
                if ((wordsList.get(ii).length() == 0)){
                    wordsList.remove(ii);
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        } 
    return wordsList;
}
```

`