# csv file has a single, double quote in one of the fields. for ex:- Data"list

Tags: java

i need to replace or remove the single double quote in my string.
For ex:- `Data"list` should be `Datalist`.
Please let me know the solution .

Comment: @khelwood this is not a duplicate of a python question.

Comment: @f1sh Quite right. I picked the wrong dupe. This one instead: [Remove all occurrences of char from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576352/remove-all-occurrences-of-char-from-string)

Comment: @AsierAranbarri the double quote must be escaped.

Comment: @khelwood I suspect the problem is about escaping the `"`, not the actual replacement

Comment: @f1sh That's why people should include their attempts.

Comment: @SanthoshArun not if you use single quotes around it, which makes this a `char`. But in that case the second argument has to be a char too.

Comment: @khelwood I agree. Hence the "suspect" :)

Comment: @f1sh and also the second char must not be left empty, it must be '\0'(null)

Comment: @SanthoshArun Then you would end up with a `\0` in the middle of your string.

Comment: @SanthoshArun your should NOT use the `\0` char in a java String, especially if you insert it into the middle of the String. You need to replace it with an empty String, see my answer below.

Comment: @f1sh I said them for char, not for String. character cannot be empty.

Comment: I forgot the scape syntax...sorry for that.

Comment: @SanthoshArun but you recommended using the `'\0'` char, which is wrong.

Comment: @f1sh yes you are right, that would leave a space.

Comment: @SanthoshArun No, it would leave a `\0`. That's different from a space.

Comment: ok i accept that it is null on screen

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace`. You need to escape the `"` since it's used in java as a delimeter to String literals:

```
String newString = oldString.replace("\"", "");
```

Comment: i guess this is to replace pair of double quotes i.e Data""list, but in my case it is Data"list.

Comment: What makes you think this replaces double quotes? Have you tried it? Do you understand what `\"` means? Why do you "guess"?