# for loop on String length weirdly skipping some chars

Tags: java, string, for-loop, char

As mentioned in the title, I am running for loop on a string being read from a file, trying to delete every `-` character, But it is weirdly deleting some and skipping others.
This is the String am working on :
[image]

this is my function :

```
        System.out.println(newSeq);
        System.out.println(" String before deleteing -  = " +newSeq + "   length  = " + newSeq.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < newSeq.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println("char at : " + i + " = " + newSeq.charAt(i) );
            // Delete every -
            if ( newSeq.charAt(i) == '-'){
                StringBuilder lineString = new StringBuilder(newSeq);
                lineString.deleteCharAt(i);
                newSeq = lineString.toString();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("String after deleting -  = " + newSeq);
```

output :

[image]

Comment: [Remove all occurrences of char from string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4576352/3890632)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem because you changed newSeq in the loop.

Suppose the input is: "1--3". On the second iteration, char will be -. Then you will replace input with "1-3". The next third iteration with index 2 will try to check the third char but the third char will be 3.

You can do it with replace:

```
    input.replace("-", "")
```

Or with regex:

```
    input.replaceAll("-+", "")
```

Or with loop:

```
    var input = "1--3";
    StringBuilder lineString = new StringBuilder();
    for (char item : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (item != '-'){
            lineString.append(item);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(lineString.toString());
```

Or with stream:

```
    var input = "1--3";
    var output = Arrays.stream(input.split(""))
            .filter(character -> !character.equals("-"))
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
    System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: makes a lot of sense I forgot that when I delete a char the length() decreases while the counter is increasing ^^' thank you

Answer (score 5):

In case you don't need to reinvent the wheel, Java already has a `replace` method:

```
newSeq = newSeq.replace("-", "");
```

Comment: first what does is the diffrence between replace('-', '\0'); and replace('-', '');
second , I kinda need to do it on loop since I need to follow the counter, because I am also trying to delete a character at the same position as the - from other String,
So actually when it gets inside the if function I use the i cursor to delete from both Strings

Comment: @4212 `replace('-', '\0')` replaces `-` with the null character `\0`. `replace('-', '')` is invalid Java because `''` is not a character. `replace("-", "")` removes all `-` characters by replacing `-` with an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

First, worth mentioning, you are iterating over an array of chars, which you are then changing in a loop.

Without diving deeply into the issue I would guess what is happening in your result string has only the last `-` removed, because of the object *re-assigning* done in the loop.

In order to do this task correctly, you need to use a new variable or use a `.replace` method on the string, which will replace each found character or part of the string with another.

To make it properly, still using a `for` loop I would advice you to create a new string called `result` for example, and then concatenate it with those characters that are allowed:

```java
String result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < newSeq.length(); i++) {
    if ( newSeq.charAt(i) != '-'){
        // this character is allowed, add it to the result
        result += newSeq.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
      // Delete every -
        if ( newSeq.charAt(i) == '-'){
            StringBuilder lineString = new StringBuilder(newSeq);
            lineString.deleteCharAt(i);
            newSeq = lineString.toString();
        }
```

This code is the problem. You are deleting a character & reassigning the reduced length string again. So the positions of right hand characters after the deletion will be shifted one position to left side. So you are getting unpredictable result.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a StringBuilder and delete starting at the end.  That way your index doesn't get out of sync. If you start from the beginning you will miss adjacent characters.  Of course, this just fixes the problem with your chosen method.  Using `String.replace()` is the simplest way.

```
String newSeq = "UCGU----ACAGU";
System.out.println(newSeq);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(newSeq);
for (int i = sb.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (sb.charAt(i) == '-') {
        sb.deleteCharAt(i);
    }
}
newSeq = sb.toString();

System.out.println(newSeq);
```

Prints

```
UCGUACAGU
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.replaceAll()` method, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String newSeq = "UCGU---AGAGU";
    
    System.out.println(newSeq);
    
    System.out.println("String before deleting '-': " + newSeq + ", length: " + newSeq.length() + "\n");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < newSeq.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Char at " + i + ": " + newSeq.charAt(i));            
    }
    
    newSeq = newSeq.replaceAll("-", "");
    
    System.out.println("\nString after deleting '-': " + newSeq);
}
```