# Android: Edittext- get current line

Tags: android, android-edittext

In an edittext is there a method for getting the current line of the cursor? If not I will write my own method, but just wanted to check. If I do write my own method would the best method be to go through every character in the edittext until selectionstart and count the number of \n's using a For loop, or is there a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just to let people know:

There is a better way to do this then Doug Paul has suggested by using the `getLineForOffset(selection)`:

```
public int getCurrentCursorLine(EditText editText)
{    
    int selectionStart = Selection.getSelectionStart(editText.getText());
    Layout layout = editText.getLayout();

    if (!(selectionStart == -1)) {
        return layout.getLineForOffset(selectionStart);
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Nice, that is indeed better!  I had pored over the API looking for a method to do this job but didn't find it at the time.  That's apparently been in there since API level 1, though.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find a simple way to get this information either, so your approach seems about right.  Don't forget to check for the case where `getSelectionStart()` returns 0.  You can make the code reusable by putting it in a static utility method, like this:

```
private int getCurrentCursorLine(Editable editable) {
    int selectionStartPos = Selection.getSelectionStart(editable);

    if (selectionStartPos < 0) {
        // There is no selection, so return -1 like getSelectionStart() does when there is no seleciton.
        return -1;
    }

    String preSelectionStartText = editable.toString().substring(0, selectionStartPos);
    return countOccurrences(preSelectionStartText, '\n');
}
```

The `countOccurrences()` method is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/), but you should use one of the better answers to that question (e.g. `StringUtils.countMatches()` from commons lang) if feasible.

I have a full working example that demonstrates this method, so let me know if you need more help.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

find the last index of "\n"using method lastindex=String.lastindexof("\n") then get a substring using method String.substring(lstindex,string.length).and you will get the last line 
in two lines of code.

Comment: The question is about finding the current line that the cursor is on, but your answer doesn't seem to address the position of the cursor.