# Convert String to int array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have one string:

```
String arr = "[1,2]";
```

ie `"[1,2]"` is like a single String.

How do I convert this `arr` to int array in java?

Comment: Your example code doesn't compile. Please fix it.  That said, have a look at StringTokenizers: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: Are you clear  of what you really want to do?

Comment: Why 8 down votes ...??

Comment: Because the question is unclear. `[1,2]` is not a valid string, and the code that the entire question is based on isn't valid java.

Comment: Do not understand why this question is downvoted. It is perfectly clear: convert `String` which has the following format: [#,#,#,#,...,#] into `int[]`

Comment: Useful, clear question that I'm needing the answer to, so much later.  The 50K+ views by now are quite telling of the question quality.  +1.

Answer (score 105):

```
String arr = "[1,2]";
String[] items = arr.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replaceAll("\\s", "").split(",");

int[] results = new int[items.length];

for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    try {
        results[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        //NOTE: write something here if you need to recover from formatting errors
    };
}
```

Comment: you sir, deserve a medal! thank you so much!! my string looked like this: [["1","2"],["11","5"]...]

Comment: this worked well, I just had to add .replaceAll(" ", "") as my string had spaces in between numbers e.g `[1313, 1314, 1315]` , without replacing spaces I would get my int[] as `[1313, 0, 0]`

Comment: `String[] items = arr.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replaceAll("\\s", "").split(",");`
could be replaced with 
`String[] items = arr.replaceAll("\\[|\\]|\\s|,", "")`

Just finished my regex class :)

Answer (score 60):

Using Java 8's stream library, we can make this a one-liner (albeit a long line):

```
String str = "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]";
int[] arr = Arrays.stream(str.substring(1, str.length()-1).split(","))
    .map(String::trim).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

`substring` removes the brackets, `split` separates the array elements, `trim` removes any whitespace around the number, `parseInt` parses each number, and we dump the result in an array.  I've included `trim` to make this the inverse of `Arrays.toString(int[])`, but this will also parse strings without whitespace, as in the question.  If you only needed to parse strings from `Arrays.toString`, you could omit `trim` and use `split(", ")` (note the space).

Comment: Thank you for adding this as answer

Answer (score 15):

```
    final String[] strings = {"1", "2"};
    final int[] ints = new int[strings.length];
    for (int i=0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(strings[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Nice concise way to implement this.  I'm definitely disappointed, though, that Java apparently hasn't thought of a one-liner in one of its libraries for this.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like JSON - it might be overkill, depending on the situation, but you could consider using a JSON library (e.g. http://json.org/java/) to parse it:

```
    String arr = "[1,2]";

    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) new JSONObject(new JSONTokener("{data:"+arr+"}")).get("data");

    int[] outArr = new int[jsonArray.length()]; 

    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        outArr[i] = jsonArray.getInt(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

try this one, it might be helpful for you

```
String arr= "[1,2]";
int[] arr=Stream.of(str.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\\, ]", "").split("")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Given that this is quite an old question, with a lot of popular answers, please edit your question to explain what your answer provides that existing ones don't. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer doesn't work properly with entries like `"[123, 456]"`

Comment: please check it now !

Comment: I think what @OlivierGrégoire is getting at is that the code only works if each element is a single digit. But it only needs a small tweak:
`Stream.of(str.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\\ ]", "").split(",")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()`

Answer (score 2):

Saul's answer can be better implemented splitting the string like this:

```
string = string.replaceAll("[\\p{Z}\\s]+", "");
String[] array = string.substring(1, string.length() - 1).split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by using StringTokenizer class defined in java.util package.

```
void main()
    {
    int i=0;
    int n[]=new int[2];//for integer array of numbers
    String st="[1,2]";
    StringTokenizer stk=new StringTokenizer(st,"[,]"); //"[,]" is the delimeter
    String s[]=new String[2];//for String array of numbers
     while(stk.hasMoreTokens())
     {
        s[i]=stk.nextToken();
        n[i]=Integer.parseInt(s[i]);//Converting into Integer
       i++;
     }
  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
  System.out.println("number["+i+"]="+n[i]);
}
```

Output :-number[0]=1
          number[1]=2

Answer (score 1):

```
    String str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0";
    String items[] = str.split(",");
    int ent[] = new int[items.length];
    for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){
        try{
            ent[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i]);
            System.out.println("#"+i+": "+ent[i]);//Para probar
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            //Error
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer an `Integer[]` instead array of an `int[]` array:

**Integer[]**

```
String str = "[1,2]";
String plainStr = str.substring(1, str.length()-1); // clear braces []
String[] parts = plainStr.split(","); 
Integer[] result = Stream.of(parts).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

**int[]**

```
String str = "[1,2]";
String plainStr = str.substring(1, str.length()-1); // clear braces []
String[] parts = plainStr.split(","); 
int[] result = Stream.of(parts).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()
```

This works for Java 8 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

In tight loops or on mobile devices it's not a good idea to generate lots of garbage through short-lived `String` objects, especially when parsing long arrays.

The method in my answer parses data without generating garbage, but it does not deal with invalid data gracefully and cannot parse negative numbers. **If your data comes from untrusted source, you should be doing some additional validation or use one of the alternatives provided in other answers.**

```
public static void readToArray(String line, int[] resultArray) {
    int index = 0;
    int number = 0;

    for (int i = 0, n = line.length(); i < n; i++) {
        char c = line.charAt(i);
        if (c == ',') {
            resultArray[index] = number;
            index++;
            number = 0;
        }
        else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            int digit = Character.getNumericValue(c);
            number = number * 10 + digit;
        }
    }

    if (index < resultArray.length) {
        resultArray[index] = number;
    }
}

public static int[] toArray(String line) {
    int[] result = new int[countOccurrences(line, ',') + 1];
    readToArray(line, result);
    return result;
}

public static int countOccurrences(String haystack, char needle) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < haystack.length(); i++) {
        if (haystack.charAt(i) == needle) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

[countOccurrences implementation was shamelessly stolen from John Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/275969/64605)

Answer (score 0):

```
String arr= "[1,2]";
List<Integer> arrList= JSON.parseArray(arr,Integer.class).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
Integer[] intArr = ArrayUtils.toObject(arrList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray());
```