# Splitting a string by multiple characters in java

Tags: java, string, replace, split

There is an input string:

```
String str="(1,6),(2,5),(7,10),(12,20)";
```

How to split the string so that an integer array containing only the integers is obtained?
i.e the output array should be: `arr={1,6,2,5,7,10,12,20};`

Comment: @Ruchira I had used the same method as that in the answer of Scadge. However, I did not know that we also had to use double backslash with the characters to be replaced. So, an error was being shown in my code..

Comment: Looks to me like you could just write something to remove the `(` and `)` and you are 99% there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is to remove all parentheses and then split by commas.

```
String str="(1,6),(2,5),(7,10),(12,20)";

//convert to string array of numbers
String[] numbersStr = str.replaceAll("\\(","").replaceAll("\\)","").split(",");

//convert to int array of numbers
int[] numbers = new int[numbersStr.length];
for(int i = 0; i < numbersStr.length; ++i)
   numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbersStr[i]);
```

Note that this is valid if you have ONLY parentheses and commas in your string, else you'll need to replace other characters with empty string before `split`.

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646392/convert-string-to-int-array-in-java) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838781/converting-string-array-to-an-integer-array).

Comment: you can sue only one `replaceAll()` like this -- `str.replaceAll("[\\(\\)]", "")`

Comment: Sure, but I think my version is a more readable. The string doesn't seem to be very large, so it won't affect the productivity much.

Answer (score 5):

You could use regex like this :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "(1,6),(2,5),(7,10),(12,20)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
        li.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group())); 
    }
    // convert li to array here if you want.

}
```

O/P :

```
1
6
2
5
7
10
12
20
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
str.replaceAll("\\(|\\)","").split(",");
```

Comment: While this might work, it is very inefficient

Comment: And is coupled to the source format, while a regex solution that searches for numbers will be transparent in case other non-numeric characters should appear later in the source string.

Answer (score 2):

Simply split by `\D+`.

You need to escape the backslash since in a string literal: `.split("\\D+")`.

You'll have empty values, don't forget to handle them ;)

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information you wrote within brackets... that was the cause of error in my code: I had not used the backslashes..