# Count exact number of charaters in a string in java

Tags: java

I have a string of names where all the different names are seperated by the same character (#) e.g. tom#will#robert#

I want to be able to count the number of names by counting the number of times that # appears, How would i go about doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I count the number of occurrences of a char in a String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

```
yourstring.splt("#").length;
```

Comment: ...only other thing is to perhaps subtract 1 iff the string does not end with a #.  Also, for very, very long Strings, manually counting may be more processor/memory friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to count the number of tokens by counting the number of the delimiters?

Just use StringTokenizer to get all tokens (set the delimiter as #) and then get its size.

```
StringTokenizer(String str, String delim)
      Constructs a string tokenizer for the specified string.
```

then:

```
 int    countTokens()
      Calculates the number of times that this tokenizer's nextToken method can be called before it generates an exception.
```