# Find number of repetitions of characters in a given Word

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, hashmap

So I was developing an algorithm to count the number of repetitions of each character in a given word. I am using a `HashMap` and I add each unique character to the `HashMap` as the key and the value is the number of repetitions. I would like to know what the run time of my solution is and if there is a more efficient way to solve the problem.

Here is the code :

```
public static void getCount(String name){
        public HashMap<String, Integer> names = new HashMap<String, Integer>() ;
        for(int i =0; i<name.length(); i++){

            if(names.containsKey(name.substring(i, i+1))){
                names.put(name.substring(i, i+1), names.get(name.substring(i, i+1)) +1);
            }
            else{
                names.put(name.substring(i, i+1), 1);
            }
        }

        Set<String> a = names.keySet();
        Iterator i = a.iterator();

        while(i.hasNext()){
            String t = (String) i.next();
            System.out.println(t + " Ocurred " + names.get(t) + " times");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this homework? I think Java has a way of counting characters? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string

Comment: No, it is not homework. I was looking at some interview questions and came across the question.

Comment: Should it be case insensitive? Should 'A' and 'a' be considered the same or different characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm has a time complexity of `O(n)`, but I'd change some parts of your implementation, namely:

- Using a single `get()` instead of `containsKey()` + `get()`;
- Using `charAt()` instead of `substring()` which will create a new `String` object;
- Using a `Map<Character, Integer>` instead of `Map<String, Integer>` since you only care about a single character, not the entire `String`:

In other words:

```
public static void getCount(String name) {
    Map<Character, Integer> names = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
        char c = name.charAt(i);
        Integer count = names.get(c);
        if (count == null) {
            count = 0;
        }
        names.put(c, count + 1);
    }
    Set<Character> a = names.keySet();
    for (Character t : a) {
        System.out.println(t + " Ocurred " + names.get(t) + " times");
    }
}
```

Comment: At first glance, I thought he had used get multiple times, but realized he hadn't, so dropped that whole optimization, but wasn't thinking about the containsKey

Comment: Even if I do use get() only once, doesn't the get() have a runtime of O(n) ? hence if it does then if the loop is repeated n times it would have a runtime of O(n^2)

Comment: @RaghavShankar: No, `get()` is constant time `O(1)`, since you are using an `HashMap`.

Comment: Oh, okay. Is there some sort of book or site where I can find the runtimes of different functions in the java library ? Such as the get() and add() functions for LinkedLists and ArrayLists and other functions associated to in built data structures in the java library

Comment: Not specifically for methods in the Java API. But Java collections tend to implement very well-known algorithms that can be found in a good Algorithms book such as *Introduction to Algorithms (Cormen et al.)*. *Some* javadoc of the classes also provide the runtime of its operations http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html.

Comment: Also see this, which provides the time complexity for many Java collections: http://www.coderfriendly.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/java_collections_v2.pdf

Comment: Not really part of the problem, but still: when you iterate to print the results, iterate on `Map.entrySet()` instead of using `Map.keySet()` + `Map.get()`, so you directly have the key and the value without doing n extra lookups.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is O(n) from an algorithmic perspective, which is already optimal (at a minimum you have to inspect each character in the entire string at least once which is O(n)).

However there are a couple of ways that you could speed it up be reducing the constant overhead, e.g.

- Use a `HashMap<Character,Integer>`. Characters will be much more efficient than Strings of length 1.
- use `charAt(i)` instead of `substring(i,i+1)`. This avoids creating a new String which will help you a lot. Probably the biggest single improvement you can make.
- If the string is going to be long (e.g. thousands of characters or more), consider using an `int[]` array to count the individual characters rather than a HashMap, with the character's ASCII value used as an index into the array. This isn't a good idea if your Strings are short though.

Comment: How do you say it is O(n) ? Within the loop I have HashMap.put(),HashMap.containsKey() and HashMap.get(). I am guessing the get() and containsKey() function have a runtime of O(n) each so when the loop is repeated n times wouldnt the runtime of the program be O(n^2) ?

Comment: @RaghavShankar You really shouldn't be using 2 calls though (see Joao's post)

Comment: get, put and containsKey are all O(1) on a HashMap (this one of the main reasons that HashMap gets used so much!). Hence doing a combination of these n times is still O(n).

Comment: Are you sure its O(1) ? I assumed it was O(n)

Comment: Yep, very sure it is O(1)! (assuming the bookkeeping is amortised and the HashMap is maintained at a reasonable capacity which is generally true in the case of the Java implementation) - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Answer (score 0):

Store the initial time to a variable, like so:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

then at the end, when you finish, print out the current time minus the start time:

```
System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms taken");
```

to see the time taken to do it. As far as I can tell, that is the most efficient way to do it, but there may be another good method. Also, use char rather than strings for each individual character (as char/Character is the best class for characters, strings for a series of chars)    then do `name.charAt(i)` rather than `name.substring(i, i+1)` and change your hashmap to HashMap<Character, Integer>

Comment: By runtime i meant if it is n, nlogn, n^2 etc Not the actual run time.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Fixed, forgot it parsed out <blah> to nothing (HTML tag)

Comment: @AlexColeman 1 - you beat me, 2. Clarification's a nasty word I shouldn't use here :P

Comment: @RaghavShankar Ahh, ok, I'm thinking it'd just be n, but not entirely sure so don't quote me on that

Answer (score 0):

String s="good";

```
    //collect different unique characters 

    ArrayList<String> temp=new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c=s.charAt(i);
        if(!temp.contains(""+c))
        {
            temp.add(""+s.charAt(i));

        }

    }

    System.out.println(temp);
    //get count of each occurrence in the string
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++) {
        int count=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {

            if(temp.get(i).equals(s.charAt(j)+"")){

                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Occurance of "+ temp.get(i) + " is "+ count+ " times" );
    }*/
```