# How to search a particular character from string and find how many times it occured

Tags: java

Store the following sentence in String

```
“JAVA IS TOUGH LANGUAGE"
```

I would like to ask a user to provide a character as an input and then print the total number of occurrence of that character in the above sentence. Moreover if a user wants to search a particular phrase or character in string he/she should able to search it.

Please tell me the simple way of beginners.

Comment: See there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string

Comment: Can Any one hElp me please :'(

Comment: i am bigginer i know about loops,arrays,methods,class,constructor,string,inputoutput method and etc but this question i couldn't understand what it means :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  String s ="JAVA IS TOUGH LANGUAGE";
       char c ='A'; //character c is static...can be modified to accept user input
    int cnt =0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        if(s.charAt(i)==c)
            cnt++;
    System.out.println("No of Occurences of character "+c+"is"+cnt);
```

Answer (score 1):

The calculation can be done in one line:

```
String sentence ="JAVA IS TOUGH LANGUAGE";
String letter = "x"; // user input

int occurs = sentence.replaceAll("[^" + letter + "]", "").length();
```

This works by replacing every character that is *not* the letter (using the regex `[^x]`) with a blank (effectively deleting it), then looking at the length of what's left.

Comment: Nothing. You have your answer of how many time the letter occurs in the sentence

Comment: @user1832150 See edited answer for an explanation of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This version the user would pass in the character they wish to search for.
So for example, from the command line they would call the program like so:

```
java TestClass A
```

This would search for "A" in the string.

```
public class TestClass {
  static String searchString = "JAVA IS TOUGH LANGUAGE";
  static public void main(String[] args) {
    int answer = 0;
    if(args.length > 0){
        char searchChar = args[0].charAt(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < searchString.length(); i++){
            if (searchString.charAt(i) == searchChar){
                answer += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of occurences of " + args[0] + " is " + answer);
  }
}
```