# Create JTree using data from text file

Tags: java, swing, text-files, jtree, defaulttreemodel

How can I create a `JTree` using data from a `.txt` file? The text file is formatted as follows:

```
Root Node
        Category A
            Sub-Category A1
                Item A1.0
                Item A1.1
                Item A1.2
            Sub-Category A2
                Item A2.0
                Item A2.1
                Item A2.2       
        Category B
            Sub-Category B1
                Item B1.0
                Item B1.1
            Sub-Category B2
                Item B2.0
                Item B2.1
            Sub-Category B3
                Item B3.0
                Item B3.1
                Sub-Sub-Category B3_1
                    Item B3_1.0
                    Item B3_1.1
        Category C
            ... etc
```

The `.txt` file contains over 700 lines.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar; well, I know how to hard code the JTree by adding nodes one by one, but that is bad programming practice - programming to implementation as opposed to programming to an interface. So I wanted a smarter way, and I came to StackOverflow, where I have learnt that it is not a place where someone just does all the hard work for you. You have challenged me to think harder and research widely, which led me to the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as [PhoenixS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491245/phoneixs) has mentioned in his answer above, the procedure involves the following steps:

1. Read the `.txt` file line by line. In this example we use [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) in conjunction with [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) OR [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html), depending on whether we are reading the `.txt` file as a resource or from the File System respectively.
2. Depending on the formatting of the `.txt` file, use the delimiter to determine the hierarchy level of each line as it is being read. Use this to create the relevant nodes of your `Jtree`. In this case the `.txt` file is tab-delimited, with the number of tabs indicating the hierarchy level.

Here is the `TreeFromTextFile` class I wrote:

```
/*
 * File: TreeFromTextFile.java
 * Created 2013-02-06
 * This Class creates a JTree using data from a Specially formatted text File.
 * The supplied text file is tab-delimited, as illustrated at:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14724014/create-jtree-using-data-from-text-file
 * 
 * You can use either InputStreamReader to read thetext file as a resource
 * or use FileReader to read the text file from the file System
 */


import java.io.BufferedReader;
//import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;

/**
 * @author engineervix
 *
 */
public class TreeFromTextFile {

private BufferedReader in;
private LineNumberReader ln;
private String line;    //value of a line in the text file
private String root;    //value to be used for the root Node of our JTree                         
private String filename = "TheTextFile.txt";
private String encoding = "UTF-8";
private DefaultMutableTreeNode top;
private JTree tree;

public TreeFromTextFile() {
    getRootNode();
    top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(root);
    createNodes(top);

    //Create a tree that allows one selection at a time.
    tree = new JTree(top);
    tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
}

//this method reads the file and prints all the lines to standard output
//for testing purposes
public void readFile() {
    try {
        //in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Path\\To\\File.txt"));
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename), encoding));

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//this method reads the first line in the text file and assigns it 
//to the root variable which will be used for the root node of our JTree
private void getRootNode() {
    try {
        //in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Path\\To\\File.txt"));
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename), encoding));
        ln = new LineNumberReader(in);

        if (ln.getLineNumber() == 0) {
            root = ln.readLine();
            //System.out.println(root);
        }

        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * this method counts the number of occurrences of a given
 * <code>char</code> in the Specified
 * <code>String</code> source:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string
 */
private int countOccurrences(String haystack, char needle) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < haystack.length(); i++) {
        if (haystack.charAt(i) == needle) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

//create the Nodes
private void createNodes(DefaultMutableTreeNode top) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode category = null;     // Level 1 in Hierarchy
    DefaultMutableTreeNode subCategory = null;  // Level 2 in Hierarchy
    DefaultMutableTreeNode leaf = null;         // Level 3 in Hierarchy    

    try {
        //in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Path\\To\\File.txt"));
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename), encoding));

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (countOccurrences(line, '\t') == 1) {
                category = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(line);
                top.add(category);
            } else if (countOccurrences(line, '\t') == 2) {
                subCategory = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(line);
                category.add(subCategory);
            } else if (countOccurrences(line, '\t') == 3) {
                leaf = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(line);
                subCategory.add(leaf);
            } //continue the else...if - if you have more levels
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public JTree getTree() {
        return tree;
    }
}
```

To test the above, I wrote the `TreeFromTextFileDemo` class, which is as shown below:

```
/*
 * Requires TreeFromTextFile.java
 */

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;

/**
 * @author engineervix
 */
public class TreeFromTextFileDemo {

private static TreeFromTextFile tr = new TreeFromTextFile();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo | Creating JTree From File.txt");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container content = frame.getContentPane();

    JTree t = tr.getTree();

    content.add(new JScrollPane(t), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(275, 300);
    frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

---

The following screenshot illustrates the output. You can use [this file](http://pastebin.com/40dAucNS) as a sample text file.

[image: output of <code>TreeFromTextFileDemo.java</code>]

Answer (score 3):

If the txt will have tabular (or spaces) well formatted, you can read the file line by line, count the number of spaces and then add the node to the tree as needed.

You can read more about JTree in java tutorial [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html).

But as @Abhishekkumar said,what have you tried? Why you can't do it? Complete your answer and don't make others do your work.

Comment: Thanks. I actually knew what to do in theory but I didn't know the implementation details. I couldn't find a concrete example online and I guess I was just being too lazy to think and come up with the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it more flexible, don't hard code the levels. Simply retain the last node at any given level using a Map. As you traverse the items in your file, you will have access to any parent node via the map. Here is the code ...

```
public class StructureBuilder {

    public static final DefaultMutableTreeNode getTreeNode(File file) throws IOException  {

        DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = null;
        Map<Integer, DefaultMutableTreeNode> levelNodes = new HashMap<Integer, DefaultMutableTreeNode>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {

            int level = getLevel(line);
            String nodeName = getNodeName(line, level);
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(nodeName);               
            levelNodes.put(level, node);
            DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = levelNodes.get(level - 1);

            if( parent != null ) {
                parent.add(node);
            }
            else {
                rootNode = node;
            }
        }    
        reader.close();
        return rootNode;
    }

    private static final int getLevel(String line) {

        int level = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++ ) {
            char c = line.charAt(i);
            if( c == '\t') {
                level++;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return level;
    }

    private static final String getNodeName(String line, int level) {
        return line.substring(level);
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and wrote a general builder class for this. It takes our source data Collection and a Hierarchy description and bingo. TreeModel.

You can also swap the structure around in real time.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29823595/4824123

Project: https://github.com/mnrussell/collectionTreeModel

Hope this helps