# find the number of every letters in a word

Tags: java, string, bar-chart

User will enter a String,
For instance if the user enters YYYCZZZZGG:
Program will evaluate the frequency of characters in the string.
For YYYCZZZZGG string, C is seen only for 1, G is repeated 2, Y has a frequency of 3, and Z’s frequency is 4.

after finding number of each letter how can I draw a bar graph using the numbers of the programs output?

Comment: *"User will enter a String, .. Program will evaluate the frequency"* Programmer will show some effort..

Comment: If you are okay with order N solution just go through all the letters then create a map M like M['C']=M['C']+1 for each occurance and then iterate over the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "YYYCZZZZGG";
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(); // Map
    // to store character and its frequency.
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        Integer count = map.get(input.charAt(i)); // if not in map
        if (count == null)
            map.put(input.charAt(i), 1);
        else
            map.put(input.charAt(i), count + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Output:

```
{G=2, C=1, Y=3, Z=4}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer is there a way taht I can convert this to acm.jar package

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache `StringUtils`:

It contains a method that can be used like `StringUtils.countMatches("YYYCZZZZGG", "Y");`

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches("YYYCZZZZGG", "C");
```

Just a matter of copy paste from [Java: How do I count the number of occurrences of a char in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string)

Comment: These: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str="YYYCZZZZGG";
    Map<Character,Integer> map=new HashMap<Character,Integer>();

    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if(map.containsKey(c))
        {
            int i=map.get(c);
            i++;
            map.put(c, i);
        }
        else
        {
            map.put(c, 0);
        }
    }

    for(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry:map.entrySet())
    {
        char c=entry.getKey();
        int  count=entry.getValue();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
 String s = "YYYCZZZZGG";
 Map<Character, Float> m = new TreeMap<Character, Float>();
 for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
     if (m.containsKey(c))
            m.put(c, m.get(c) + 1);
        else
            m.put(c, 1f);
 }

 for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
      float freq = m.get(c) / s.length();
      System.out.println(c + " " + freq);
  }
```

Or you can use StringUtils class like:

```
System.out.println("The occurrence of Z is "+StringUtils.countMatches(s, "C"));
```