# Reading a line from a text file Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I am trying to read a line from a file using BufferedReader and Scanner. I can create both of those no problem. What I am looking to do is read one line, count the number of commas in that line, and then go back and grab each individual item. So if the file looked like this:

item1,item2,item3,etc.

item4,item5,item6,etc.

The program would return that there are four commas, and then go back and get one item at a time. It would repeat for the next line. Returning the number of commas is crucial for my program, otherwise, I would just use the Scanner.useDelimiter() method. I also don't know how to return to the beginning of the line to grab each item.

Comment: A couple of the answers below give `str.length` for the number of commas.  Technically the actual number of commas would be `str.length-1` since there are `str.length` items (with commas in between each).  Just wanted to make sure that was mentioned.

Comment: @thesquaregroot Good point, I forgot he was counting commas not tokens.

Comment: Reading your question again though, you say there are 4 commas in your examples, but there are actually only 3 (there are 4 items). So maybe `str.length` is right if you did actually want the number of items.

Comment: @thesquaregroot great point. Technically I asked about the num of commas, but the actual length will do for my purposes. Good eye though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just split the `String`.  The `split` method accepts a delimiter (regex) as an argument and breaks the `String` into a `String[]`.  This will eliminate the need to `return to the beginning`.

```
String value = "item1,item2,item3";
String[] tokens = value.split(",");
```

To get the number of commas, just use, `tokens.length - 1`

[String.split() Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Awesome :) didn't know about that method for string!

Comment: @thesquaregroot Yep, I just noticed that when testing my code. Thanks!

Comment: Chosen, because all answers were similar, and he was first. Also he added documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Split() can be used to achieve this
eg:

```
String Line = "item1,item2,item3"
String[] words =Line.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must know the number of commas, a similar question has already been answered:

[Java: How do I count the number of occurrences of a char in a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string)