# Java function for number of colons in a CSV file

Tags: java, csv

What function should i use for Java programming to get the total number of colons in a CSV file?

PS: not a Java developer.

Comment: Do you care at all about the commas?

Comment: That's a ridiculous close reason.  What more information could OP have provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the file char by char (using a BufferedReader to make it fast), and count each colon you meet:

```
int countColons() throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file.txt), "UTF-8"))) {
        int count = 0;
        int c;
        while ((c = in.read()) >= 0) {
            if (c == ':') {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Of course, you should use the appropriate encoding for your file. Not necessarily UTF-8.

Comment: +1 for not loading the entire file into memory.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file line by line.  For every line, use `replaceAll` to get rid of every character that isn't a colon.  Then get the length of the resulting `String`.  Keep a cumulative total of the results of this.

Comment: replaceAll to count characters? Why not read the file char by char and count the ones equal to a colon? Sounds much more logical and efficient to me.

Comment: @JBNizet you could post that as an answer.  I'll upvote it if you do.

Comment: @DavidWallace Why line by line when `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` reads the entire file to a String? :-)

Comment: @corsiKa Because very often, one must deal with files that are really big.  If you're only processing a file in start-to-finish order, you really don't want to use up a huge amount of heap space doing so.  I am a bit dismayed by how many of the answers here start by loading the entire file into memory - it's really not good practice.

Comment: @DavidWallace I find that very hard to swallow. I can't remember the last time I had to deal with something that big. If it really is that big, it shouldn't be in a file, it should be in a database.

Comment: @corsiKa Happens *all* the time. You can argue that you should read it into a DB or key/value store, but that's an additional, potentially unnecessary step. There are a bunch of reasons why passing around files is reasonable under a variety of conditions.

Comment: @corsiKa Well, in my current job, I frequently have to deal with enormous files.  Like hundreds of megabytes of XML.  It would seem a bit rich to assume that the OP doesn't.  But whether he does or not, we should be promoting best practices in our answers.  And loading a file into memory when you only need to read it from start to finish is absolutely _not_ a best practice.

Comment: @DavidWallace I disagree with your last assertion. I think doing extra work because it might save some heap space, at the expense of making the code much less readable and straightforward, is a bad practice. And it can be argued both ways, but personally I'd say leave it simple (as per wypieprz's solution) unless you've identified there's a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel:

```java
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

int count = StringUtils.countMatches(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("file.csv")), ":");
```

Comment: This is excellent - knowing these kinds of utilities makes mundane tasks just disappear so we can focus on more important development work.

Answer (score 0):

One cool trick I found a while ago for counting the number of occurences is to take the length of the `string`, and minute all the values from it that are not your desired value.

**Example**

```
// Assume fileStr contains everything in the file

int numberOfColons = fileStr.length() - fileStr.replaceAll(":", "").length();
```

This will give you the number of colons in the file.

**Edit**

Just remembered when I got it from. It is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275944/how-do-i-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-char-in-a-string).

**The reason why I like this approach**

Obviously, it's extremely short, which is always nice. It does give some of a hit to the processor, but it avoids all loops (in your code at least) and it seems like a very elegant solution to the problem.